# How can I run Windows applications in Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install windows Software in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-in-ubuntu)

How do I run Windows' applications  in Ubuntu ?