# Is there any way I can setup AirPort Express from Ubuntu?

Tags: 11.04, wireless, apple

Offical source says it's not possible and also couldn't find anything more about setting it up apart from OS X or Windows manuals.

Comment: If there's a Windows application to configure the base station, maybe it'll [run under Wine](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9372/how-can-i-run-windows-applications-in-ubuntu/56057#56057).

Comment: Haven't tried myself but I can confirm that for some people the setup program for the AEX runs fine with Wine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running an Airport Express wireless AP. I can configure it with a Java app, called `AirportBaseStationConfigurator`, which is part of a Java source package called `AirportAdministration`, written by J. Sevy. I forget where I got it, but I recall that google was my friend, it could be yours, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can download [AirPort Utility 5.6.1](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1547) for Windows and run it under [WineHQ](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Plug the printer into the airport express

Then in ubuntu go into the printer setup control panel, click to add a new printer, and select the network printer option.  The printer connected to the express should show up.  Now follow all the prompts to install drivers and viola!