# How can I Play Windows games in Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: windows, wine, games

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I run Windows applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9372/how-can-i-run-windows-applications-in-ubuntu)

Currently I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and I have tried installing Windows games with Wine, but some games like NFS require the latest version of DirectX.  What should I do to play games in Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you try installing Windows in a Virtual Machine inside Ubuntu and running the game there?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately wine for linux is far from perfect and there is little to zero dx10 and dx11 support, even making dx9 games to work usually requires a fair bit of hacking around, which is why wine is not suited to run recent windows games (older games work like a charm though.
so you have two choices, either run windows inside virtual machines like virtual box, which incurs performance penalties or set up a dual booting machine with windows and ubuntu.
hope this is helpful