# How to run the windows application inside Ubuntu?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I run Windows applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9372/how-can-i-run-windows-applications-in-ubuntu)

I want to run the Windows based applications inside Ubuntu. How can I do that?. Some of the application only runs on the Windows OS. Please help me.

Thanks,
Krishna