# Is it possible to install games like Defense of the Ancients in ubuntu?

Tags: compatibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I run Windows applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9372/how-can-i-run-windows-applications-in-ubuntu)

let's just say I'm already a little bit pro in using Ubuntu but I haven't try to install some of my favorite games in Ubuntu. Is it possible to put games like we usually play in windows? and How can I install them in Ubuntu?

Comment: Dual boot with windows if you love games like me! :p

Comment: Short answer: yes, but not all of them and it's usually tricky. You can play DOS games without any problems, as there's an awesome DOS emulator: dosbox.

Answer (score 0):

The answer here can't be precise. You can play Windows games on **Linux** using softwares such as Wine (*free*) and CrossOver Games (*paid*), that simulate Windows's APIs.

The performance in some games are actualy better than playing it in Windows, like Counter Strike 1.6 for example, but lots of games simple won't play. There is a software database that shows lots of softwares and games that run with Wine, with how tos and stuffs.

But be aware that Wine can be tricky and kinda depends on your hardware. A game may play fine on NVidia graphic cards but not with Intel ones for example, even if it used to play fine on Windows.

On a side note, [Warcraft III received a platinum score on Wine App DB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=3126), so i would say it play just fine, but never tryed it myself since i prefer to play native **Linux** games (*and trust me, there ARE lots of them*).

Wine is on **Ubuntu**'s repositories, so all you have to do is type this on terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

The [Wine App DB can be find here](http://appdb.winehq.org/index.php). You could also look at [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/), a front end to Wine that implement lots of the how tos and do it themselfs, prety cool. And if nothing of that helps, you might want to try Cross Over Games, a paid software (: