# How can I make the Windows game Feltstars work on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, windows, wine, games

[FeltStars.com](http://feltstars.com) is a Windows download, how can I make that work with ubuntu ?

I'm using 12.04 just downloaded and installed it last night. By the way, I do not want to have both windows and Ubuntu operating systems, I only want to use ubuntu, can I make the Felt Stars program work

Comment: AskUbuntu works best with one question per page. Would you mind asking a separate question about your camera? You should mention what it is and how it connects. After you do you can expect members of the community to then ask you for more information from your computer in an effort to determine why it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9372/how-can-i-run-windows-applications-in-ubuntu) for information on how you might be able to directly execute the program you already have under Ubuntu.

Looking at http://linuxowns.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/playing-poker-on-ubuntu/ I can see there  there is at least one native Ubuntu application. It mentions PokerTH.

You might want to take a look for games you might like in the Ubuntu Software Center.