# How do I make windows games run smoothly on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, windows, games

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I run Windows applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9372/how-can-i-run-windows-applications-in-ubuntu)

I need help in making windows games like GTA, FEAR, COD, Company of heroes etc. run smoothly on ubuntu 12.04. I want this on my Hp Compaq dx6100mt pc, i am having an intel graphics card.

Answer (score 1):

For windows games in Ubuntu you should try [PlayonLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/).
It is a front end for Wine, but more user friendly and helps you install many games.

Other options are [Crossovergames](http://www.codeweavers.com/products/) (you have to buy a license after trial period) or just use Wine. [WineHQ](http://www.winehq.org/) has good tutorials.

Good luck!

Comment: I already have playonlinux. But the games that I have installed dont run properly and creates so much errors too. I need them to run smoothly. So, right now, I need a Intel Graphics Accelerator for ubuntu, which I dont have. How can I get it?