# Why can i download anything from the internet?

Tags: helpfile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How can I run Windows applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9372/how-can-i-run-windows-applications-in-ubuntu)

I get this error message:

> Archive: /home/nicole/Downloads/iLividSetupV1.exe
> [/home/nicole/Downloads/iLividSetupV1.exe] End-of-central-directory
> signature not found. Either this file is not a zipfile, or it
> constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive. In the latter case the
> central directory and zipfile comment will be found on the last
> disk(s) of this archive.
>
> zipinfo: cannot find zipfile directory in one
> of /home/nicole/Downloads/iLividSetupV1.exe or
> /home/nicole/Downloads/iLividSetupV1.exe.zip, and cannot find
> /home/nicole/Downloads/iLividSetupV1.exe.ZIP.

Why is ubuntu doing this?. I can no longer use my ipod, download songs, download software.

Comment: Ubuntu is NOT Windows. It's not worse or better. It's different.

Comment: iLivid qualifies as malware in my book.

Answer (score 2):

The iLivid downloader program is an *.exe, a **Windows** executable. You may want to look at the [Wine Project](http://www.winehq.org/about/) if you need iLivid to download another file.

[Wine [image: Install wine]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine) is available for Ubuntu in the Software center.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you tried to open a broke zip file

Also anything that ends in .exe is a M$-Windows package, it cannot be installed on Ubuntu. You can install .debs, or use the ***Ubuntu Software Center*** application to install software.

Ubuntu is not a garbage OS, but it may not be for you.