# How do I install wine?

Tags: software-installation, wine

Can someone please explain how I can install [wine](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wine1.3)[image: Install wine] in the following ways?

1. By using the package manager?
2. By downloading and installing a pre-built package?

Comment: It's fine you accepted your own solution, but it only explains the first part of your question.

Comment: I have reworded your question a bit to clarify and make it a little clearer. Please feel free to make any corrections if I have changed the meaning of the question at all.

Comment: For complete instructions see http://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine

Comment: sudo apt-get install wine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can install it through Synaptic or from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Answer (score 20):

1. You can install [wine](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wine) [image: Install wine] using the Ubuntu Software Centre and search for "wine", select the first one and press install. Also you can install PlayOnLinux which is a GUI for helping you install Windows Software into Ubuntu Linux.

   [image: Software Center screenshot]
2. Usually there are no pre-downloaded files in Linux world because you also have to find and download all the dependencies!!! That is why it is better to install programs through Software Centre that will deal with any dependencies.

Comment: could you tell me to install it through pre- downloaded wine.tar file?

Comment: if you want to try to compile the source code you can download it from here http://ibiblio.org/pub/linux/system/emulators/wine/wine-1.2.1.tar.bz2

Read the "Read Me" file that is included for details to how compile and install wine.

Comment: @SalihEmin The first option that I have now (+2 years later) is the meta package. Should I install it or the first option of your screenshoot (Microsoft Windows Compatibility Layer (BE and lib))?

Comment: @Lucio if the first option is available, then install it. If not the metapackage should pull the same packeges

Comment: I didn't know if any option would install the same packages or not so I was very confused. But now I understand that [the meta-package will install all the package necessary](http://askubuntu.com/q/66257/62483). Thanks for your reply!

Comment: This [no longer works as of Feb 2017](http://askubuntu.com/questions/879304/wine-2-0-says-it-supports-office-2013-how-do-i-actually-install-it).

Answer (score 4):

You can install it via the [wine PPA](http://www.winehq.org/download/deb). In the terminal type the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine wine1.8
```

That should leave you with the latest 1.8.x version.

Now to have a working and enhanced Wine environment for your games, I suggest you use `winetricks` to install additional components to have better compatibility with games for example. Follow this links to have a better working system:

[How do I install Half-Life 1 and 2?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/129664/how-do-i-install-half-life-1-and-2?lq=1) - Which covers winetricks usage.

[Shader Model 3.0 not recognized in Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102710/shader-model-3-0-not-recognized-in-wine) - Which covers some information regarding Shader Model 3.0. At least until it is supported in Wine.

[World of Warcraft on PlayOnLinux: graphics problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66959/world-of-wacraft-on-playonlinux-graphics-problem/66970#66970) - Which checks to see if you have correct OpenGL support.

[How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/which-driver-should-i-install-when-using-an-nvidia-ati-or-intel-video-card) - Which covers driver installation to have better support for OpenGL

[Adjusting resolution for individual Wine programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16733/adjusting-resolution-for-individual-wine-programs/16761#16761) - Which covers special cases where you would want to edit the resolution or other settings related to Wine and multiple apps.

Comment: This link is a much simpler way of doing the same thing: http://www.winehq.org/download/deb

Comment: I can not agree more. Even more if you are THE Scott Ritchie hehe. Anybody read this, follow his method. It is the reason am using wine in the first place ;)  
  
On a side note: Do not know if you could add `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get remove wine && apt-get install wine1.3` to your ppa, just like a small note to users that want to just type it. That way it makes sure the user has wine 1.3.x installed from your ppa

Comment: Re *WAY 4*: I'm not 100% clear about the whys and wherefores, but `software-properties-gtk` is a graphical application... `sudo` is for command line apps, `gksu/gksudo` for graphical ones... [Why should I use gksudo for Gtk apps instead of sudo?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/51572/why-should-i-use-gksudo-for-gtk-apps-instead-of-sudo) ... Quoting from a link on that page: *Bottom line: most of the time when you use sudo for graphical applications, it's fine. Some of the time, though, it is not fine, and is, in fact, extremely bad.*

Comment: I removed the step 4 since is redoing the gksu part but from my own experience doing sudo for a gui app has always been fine and you would need to show me where the "extremely bad" part comes in. Both sudo and gksu are calling the same procedures to load the app as a semi-root for the time the app is opened.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article. This will help you to install wine from source : http://tuxarena.blogspot.com/2009/06/3-ways-to-install-latest-wine-in-ubuntu.html

Check it out.