# What is a good MySQL manager?

Tags: software-recommendation, mysql

On Windows, I use SQLyog. And I am new to Ubuntu.

Is there a mysql manager programs as good as SQLyog ?

Answer (score 10):

The repository contains the `mysql-admin` package which is a GUI tool for administrating MySQL. From the package's description:

> GUI tool for intuitive MySQL
>   administration
>
> MySQL Administrator is a powerful
>   visual administration console that
>   enables you to easily administer your
>   MySQL environment and gain
>   significantly better visibility into
>   how your databases are operating.
>
> MySQL Administrator integrates
>   database management and maintenance
>   into a single, seamless environment,
>   with a clear interface.

[image: MySQL GUI screenshot]

Comment: thanks , i will test it. I see it is defrecated to use Workbench http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html

Comment: @meotimdihia -> wrong that link is too old ... http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html

Comment: The project is EOL. See http://askubuntu.com/a/127924/446263

Answer (score 7):

[image]
You can use - [Valentina Studio](http://www.valentina-db.com/en/valentina-studio-overview),the program is free. It works on 3 OS: MAC, WIN, LIN. It works as with MySQL, so with PostgreSQL, SQLite and Valentina DB.

I am pleased with this program.

Answer (score 5):

You can use SQLyog on Wine/LINUX with GNOME desktop see [product page](http://www.webyog.com/en/screenshots.php?ref=2) in TAB SQLyog on Wine/Linux

- [How do I install wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15518/how-do-i-install-wine)

Answer (score 2):

On Windows I use Devart's MySQL GUI Manager ( http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/ ), but it doesn't work at Ubuntu. So I'll recommend to use WorkBench ( http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/5.2.html )!

Answer (score 1):

The MYSQL Administrator, which you can install in the Software Center, is a pretty good GUI management tool.

Comment: it has probably been disabled from The 12.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

I use this tools and recommend this list for you.

1. MySQL Workbench (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)
2. HeidiSQL (http://www.heidisql.com/)
3. NaviCat

I love using **MySQL Workbench** because easier for me to manage mysql server, and the reverse/foward engineering are very good.

But when doing code, I prefer **HeidiSQL** which much simple and sleek. But **NaviCat** also are good tools to have. It help me to structure the complex sql query.

I hope this list and reason behind I use this tool can help you to decide and choose ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) on ubuntu. It is an eclipse style platform independent tool, which is very powerful and feature rich, and receives regular updates.