# Where are mysql-admin and query-browser?

Tags: apt, mysql

In terminal I run next commands:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install mysql-admin
sudo apt-get install mysql-query-browser
```

With  first command - all  ok.

But for latest two commands: `Unable to locate package.`

My question: Why I can't install admin and query browser?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

MySQL has officially declared EOL (End of Life) for Query Browser. You can check it on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/query-browser/en/

[MySQL Workbench [image: Install mysql-workbench]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mysql-workbench) is its replacement and its now available in Ubuntu 12.04 repositories:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

All features are supported by Workbench.

[image: Install via the software center]

Comment: Confirm that mysql-workbench is in 12.04, please, there's rumors its not, and a bunch of packaging request bugs for it to be *in* 12.04.

Comment: I can confirm that `mysql-workbench` is in the archives.

Comment: @ThomasW.Don't take our word for it, you can always check such the status of packages Ubuntu releases: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=mysql-workbench&searchon=names

Answer (score 6):

Bummer:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-gui-tools/+bug/896463

There is mysql-workbench ...
https://launchpad.net/~olivier-berten/+archive/misc

```
aptitude show mysql-query-browser
aptitude show mysql-workbench
aptitude show tora
```

Well, the workstation running 12.04 on which I found mysql-query-browser, was updated from 10.04 to 12.04 - it was retained across the upgrade - so that is a different situation than a non-upgrade clean install of 12.04 .

Also, I have found a PPA:
http://www.tolaris.com/2012/05/16/added-to-precise-repository-handbrake-mysql-query-browser/

Comment: Unfortunately - on Linux anyway - mysql-workbench is a mess. It's bloated with crap I don't need and is just way worse to use for everything I use the query browser for. I just want a simple tool to connect to the db and run queries (with tabs), but I guess now I'll have to go somewhere else to find it, yay.

Comment: I tried the workbench for a few days but it used up all memory of my machine so I had to kill it. So for me it's completely useless now. I hope it's still possible to install the query-browser somehow.

Comment: @Zitrax: it's free software, so you can always compile from source and run it :)

Answer (score 2):

I found precise instructions and the packages that worked for me without any hassle 
[here](http://www.tolaris.com/2012/05/16/added-to-precise-repository-handbrake-mysql-query-browser/). Hope this helps people.

PS: Do not forget to reload the repositories.

Answer (score 2):

After about 2 years since I stopped using MySQL Admin and MySQL Query Browser because for me they were the best and I was force to use MySQL Workbench, I am posting this answer here to let others that used to use Admin and Query Browser because of their ease of use (Which was removed in Workbench) to know that the current MySQL Workbench has gotten to a point where, it is not only as great as Admin / Query Browser, but also incorporate the best of Workbench and other similar MySQL tools.

It is currently awesome. Here are some images of how it now looks (Last timed I used workbench as 2 years ago).

[image]

[image]

So right now, MySQL Workbench (This would be the first time I say this) offers everything MySQL Admin and MySQL Query Browser offered several years ago, plus a lot of new things to play with. Gave me a reason to install it again.

Answer (score 1):

If you think as many others that unfortunately mysql-workbench is not a good and a simple tool to do quick and fine things, you can install previous deleted tools directly from the repository manually. You just have to download and install the following .deb packages:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/mysql-gui-tools-common/5.0r14+openSUSE-2.2ubuntu2
  https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/libmysqlclient16/5.1.58-1ubuntu5
   launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/mysql-query-browser/5.0r14+openSUSE-2.2ubuntu2
   launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/mysql-admin/5.0r14+openSUSE-2.2ubuntu2

Of course this is for amd64 architecture, for the i386 just change the link.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.tolaris.com/2012/05/16/added-to-precise-repository-handbrake-mysql-query-browser/

Summary:  add the Tolaris "Precise" repository to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, GUI Tools should then be available to be installed.

Update:  does not seem to work with Xenial,  have not discovered a way to get the old GUI tools to work.