# How to install MySQL GUI Tools in 12.04+ versions?

Tags: mysql

I want to install the MySQL GUI Tools in 12.04 and future version because frankly the way workbench works is not even close to how friendly the GUI tools were, specially for simple stuff like doing a quick SELECT of something or selecting a table. I like using MySQL Administrator and MySQL Query Browser. The way they work is much more intuitive than Workbench. How can I install them in 12.04 and newer versions?

Comment: See http://www.tolaris.com/2012/05/16/added-to-precise-repository-handbrake-mysql-query-browser/

Comment: Are you sure that workbench meets your needs the best? As for me I am using dbForge MySQL GUI. Read more about it here: http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I tried to compile without success because many bugs to fix :(
2. I tried to convert .rpm package with alien, its convert and install well but doesn't work :(
3. go to this [page](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html) and download this packed : **see UPDATE**

32 bits

**`Generic x86 Linux TAR (bundled dependencies)         5.0r12`**

```
mysql-gui-tools-5.0r12-linux-i386.tar.gz
```

64 bits

**`Generic x86/64 Linux TAR (bundled dependencies)      5.0r12`**

```
mysql-gui-tools-5.0r12-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

4. extract the tar.gz with nautilus doble-click :

[image]

1. Open mysql-gui-tools-5.0 with nautilus an you will see :

[image]

1. The first time open a terminal an execute `./mysql-administrator`

[image]

if you see one error like that just execute `./mysql-administrator --update-paths`

1. for second time an more just execute via nautilus

[image]

and voala! happy rocking...

### UPDATE 23/02/2013

MYSQL Announcement the **EOL** for the MySQL GUI Tools Bundle (Administrator, Query Browser, Migration Toolkit), please use MySQL Workbench has replaced the GUI Tools Bundle instead, and you can't download from the MYSQL web page but I found another page where you can find it:

- [MySQLGUITools](http://mysql.azc.uam.mx/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/)

Comment: Hi hhlp, can you provide an updated answer. The link provided does not have the needed packages. Thanks.

Comment: Excuse me. I am running Ubuntu 13.04. When I run `./mysql-administrator`. It show the error: `Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 4):

A better solution is in this link. [Where are mysql-admin and query-browser?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121391/where-are-mysql-admin-and-query-browser-for-latest-version-ubuntu-12-04)

It's just a question of running this: sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench

The explanation for this new name "workbench" is in the link above

HTH

Comment: Honestly I hate the workbench change. I rather work in the terminal than on it. The only use I have with that non intuitive version is to create a database map for a relational model. Apart from that I found that the previous versions (Admin and Query) and the terminal, at least for me, help me solve my problems quickly. Of course all of this is just a timed excuse while I learn how to use workbench correctly. After that I won't have a problem with it.

Answer (score 2):

This is for 12.04+ users:

Since MYSQL has taken the link down, the only quick place I found the compressed MySQL GUI Tools was here:

http://mysql.ntu.edu.tw/Downloads/MySQLGUITools/mysql-gui-tools-5.0r14.tar.gz

So download that, decompress and follow the steps mentioned by hhlp [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/138638/7035). Note that you need to compile it yourself. There is an `autogen.sh` file in both the Admin and Query folders. Run it and it will tell you what else you need to have it working.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.tolaris.com/2012/05/16/added-to-precise-repository-handbrake-mysql-query-browser/

While there are many possible paths to install (depending on your setup),  in more recent versions of Ubuntu (12+) you may manually add the following sources to /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://www.tolaris.com/apt/ precise main
deb-src http://www.tolaris.com/apt/ precise main
```

Then:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install mysql-gui-tools

(If your version of Ubuntu has been upgraded,  you may need to update *.archive.ubuntu.org sources to your current release,  as well-- for instance,  to 'saucy').

This seems the only viable path to installing the GUI tools at this point,  as all other sources are offline.

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL Announcement the EOL for the MySQL GUI Tools Bundle (Administrator, Query Browser, Migration Toolkit), please use MySQL Workbench has replaced the GUI Tools Bundle instead, and you can't download from the MYSQL web page but I found another page where you can find it:

Comment: This answer seems rather unclear, could you [edit] it to expand on your answer and provide the link which you mention

Comment: I found it  [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/)

Answer (score -1):

Run these commands in the Terminal:

```
aptitude search mysql-query-browser mysql-admin mysql-workbench
```

```
aptitude show tora
```

Comment: sorry but mysql-query-browser and mysql-admin are not available in ubuntu 12.04 only available in ubuntu <= 11.10

Comment: Ah, the workstation running 12.04 on which I found mysql-query-browser, was updated from 10.04 to 12.04 - it was retained across the upgrade - so that is a different situation than a non-upgrade clean install of 12.04 .

MySQL-Workbench is available, and tora is worth a look.

Also, I have found a PPA for mysql-query-browser:
http://www.tolaris.com/2012/05/16/added-to-precise-repository-handbrake-mysql-query-browser/