# A couple of minor issues after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gnome, 14.04, desktop-background, dropbox

Hey guys so I just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm having a couple of issues that I can't find an answer for:

1)Dropbox Icon is very large in the gnome menu, very annoying.

2)Variety will remove desktop icons when switching wallpapers. I can re-enable them through the ubuntu tweak tool but I would have to do it every time that it changes a wallpaper.

[image: example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1). For desktop, find the file in `/usr/share/applications/` - it'll likely be called "dropbox.desktop"

find the line that reads: `Icon=` and either change it to the full path of your own icon, or simply pop open GIMP and scale down the icon where it sits.

2). For Variety, I would recommend using something officially endorsed, such as the [Automatic Wallpaper Changer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/raring/wallch/) , or try one of [these applications](http://www.maketecheasier.com/3-awesome-ubuntu-apps-for-wallpaper-slideshow/)

Comment: You will need edit the permissions of the icon(s)/desktop file to edit it as a normal user... or run it as root, if using a GUI program, you may want to use [`gksudo`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/51572/why-should-i-use-gksudo-for-gtk-apps-instead-of-sudo) or [`pkexec`](http://askubuntu.com/questions/313828/why-is-pkexec-preferred-over-gksudo-for-graphical-applications). There are also likely to be different scales of the icon, you can find them with `locate dropbox.png`

Comment: @rm-vanda it seems that slidewall isn't supported at the moment