# Is sudo -i less secure than pkexec?

Tags: sudo, pkexec

I just heard that it isn't recommended to use `sudo -i` on GUI programs - because it's less secure.

Is there any truth here - is there an advantage to this:

```
sudo -i gedit /random/file.name
```

over

```
pkexec gedit /random/file.name
```

I used to use gksudo, but that's been phased out, so now I use `sudo -i` to [prevent root owning files in my home area](https://askubuntu.com/a/632814/186134). But should I really be using `pkexec`?

Here is a reason:

> The environment that PROGRAM will run [in], will be set to a minimal known and safe environment in order to avoid injecting code through `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or similar mechanisms. In addition the `PKEXEC_UID` environment variable is set to the user id of the process invoking `pkexec`.

Comment: There is nothing which is hidden from a `root` user with UID 0

Comment: Where did you hear it? I see nothing mentioned so far that `sudo` can't do (it can reset environment variables, and see the variables `SUDO_USER` and `SUDO_UID`).

Comment: @muru the developer of elementary OS told me, saying I shouldn't use `sudo` in my answer.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/eOXhJ.png

Comment: IMHO unless he can show a scenario demonstrating what he meant, he's just passing on "received wisdom" (to put it politely). I feel the only benefit of `pkexec` is that another user can authorize for you, but I'm no security expert. By the way, we can still view the eOS.se beta, so you can link to the discussion directly.

Comment: @muru http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/52/3

Comment: Curious: `pkexec` needs to be configured to run graphical programs. Ubuntu, Debian and Arch Linux don't configure it for that by default. Does elementary OS? If not, asking users to use `pkexec` is just a hassle. And where there's hassle, users will switch to easier commands.

Comment: @muru no, it's not. Hmm, I'll mention that,

Comment: Not sure about the question, but AFAIK `sudo -H` is also enough. However I was recently downvoted on an answer in which I suggested this, so maybe I'm wrong on this one

Comment: ahum: http://askubuntu.com/questions/78352/when-to-use-pkexec-vs-gksu-gksudo

Answer (score -1):

I think the security concern you are referring to comes from the fact that if you use sudo, with or without the -i, you have an active permission to run sudo commands, for 5 minutes. If you were to do `sudo vim /file.txt` then leave, your computer unattended the sudo session would still be active. someone could come along and type `sudo rm /file.txt` or worse.

pkexec will prompt you for a password every-time, which would seem a little more secure.

I think Elementary OS is intended for schools, where the physical environment shouldn’t be considered secure. Students may well show up at your desk moments after you leave.  Comparatively, in my Business office, where only 3 folks have the key, and my computer is moderately secure in the physical sense, I'm less concerned with untrusted individuals running in and using my PC unsupervised. If I run sudo command, then leave, I'm assuming no one will come in and give malicious sudo commands.

I make no claim to be a security expert, but I think that is what the elementary OS folks are thinking.

Comment: Both `sudo` and `pkexec` can be configured to ask for a password every time, or keep the auth token for a few minutes.

Comment: many things can be configured. the defaults are what get used.

Comment: In that case the packagers could have changed the default config instead of deprecating `gksudo`. It would have been less work.