# How does sudo handle $HOME differently since 19.10?

Tags: sudo, home-directory, environment-variables, 19.10, history-of-ubuntu

In Ubuntu releases prior to Ubuntu 19.10 Eoan Ermine, when I run a command with `sudo`, that command receives *my home directory* in the `$HOME` environment variable. This is the behavior I have long expected and [warned other people about](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications). If I want `sudo` to reset the `$HOME` environment variable, so that it refers to the target user's home directory instead of my own, I have to pass the `-H` option (or `-i`, though that does more).

```bash
ek@Kip:~$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
ek@Kip:~$ sudo printenv HOME  # Shows ek's home, not root's.
/home/ek
ek@Kip:~$ sudo -u as printenv HOME  # Shows ek's home, not as's.
/home/ek
ek@Kip:~$ sudo -H printenv HOME  # Shows root's home.
/root
ek@Kip:~$ sudo -Hu as printenv HOME  # Shows as's home.
/home/as
```

When I first upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10, I was surprised to discover that ***`sudo` seems to reset `$HOME` no matter what!*** I continue to observe this now that 19.10 is released and I've installed updates--both on newly installed systems and one I upgraded to 19.10.

```bash
ek@Cord:~$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
ek@Cord:~$ sudo printenv HOME  # Shows root's home, even without -H or -i.
/root
ek@Cord:~$ sudo -u as printenv HOME  # Shows as's home, even without -H or -i.
/home/as
ek@Cord:~$ sudo -H printenv HOME  # Also shows root's home.
/root
ek@Cord:~$ sudo -Hu as printenv HOME  # Also shows as's home.
/home/as
```

I thought this might be due to [updated configuration files](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#conffiles).  But I checked, and `always_set_home` does not appear in any `Defaults` line in my 19.10 `/etc/sudoers` file.

**What makes `sudo` treat `$HOME` differently starting in 19.10, and why was this change made?** Does this make it safe to use plain `sudo` in cases where I would previously have used `sudo -H`?

Comment: If you're like me and you want to preserve all the unhygienic behavior: `sudo bash -c 'HOME=/home/[username] ; [command]'`

Comment: I think it is worth to mention this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504662/how-to-get-home-directory-of-different-user-in-bash-script
You can create something like `SUDO_HOME=\`eval echo "~$SUDO_USER"\``

Answer (score 122, accepted):

For years, Ubuntu has [shipped a patched version of `sudo` that preserves `$HOME` by default](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/760140). Besides Ubuntu and its derivatives, [very few other operating systems (perhaps no others) do this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1556302/comments/8). It has been [**decided that this causes more problems than it solves**](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1556302), and [starting in Ubuntu 19.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1556302/comments/16), `$HOME` is no longer one of the few environment variables `sudo` preserves.

In terms of *what* the change is and how it affects users, the key points are:

- **As of Ubuntu 19.10, `sudo command` does what `sudo -H command` does in previous releases.** It [can indeed be used](https://askubuntu.com/a/1047413/22949) in cases that would have previously advised `sudo -H`, including [to run GUI applications as root or another user](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#General_workarounds). Running graphical programs as root at all [remains controversial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162608/can-there-ever-be-any-problem-when-using-gedit-to-edit-system-files-with-sudo). But in 19.10 you can run `sudo gedit` with the exact same effect as `sudo -H gedit`. In 19.10, commands like `sudo gedit` no longer create [annoying file ownership problems](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications) in your home directory.
- **This applies *even* on systems upgraded to 19.10 from an earlier release**, even when the upgrade doesn't change your `/etc/sudoers` file. The change is in the source code of the `sudo` program itself, not in its default configuration files. (It can be overridden in a `sudoers` file, but you'd probably know if you did this.)
- **It doesn't--and won't--apply to releases prior to 19.10.** Before 19.10, `sudo` preserves `$HOME` by default, and future updates to `sudo` won't change that. For example, 18.04 LTS will always have the old behavior, even in future point releases.
- **`sudo -H command` still works fine.** If you're in the habit of using that, no problem. You just don't have to, on a 19.10 system.
- ***Most* commands you run with `sudo` won't behave differently.** In the overwhelming majority of situations where you would *not* have passed `-H`, you *could* have. Some users do [rely on or otherwise prefer the old behavior](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2019-May/018347.html) of preserving `$HOME`. But that [often had unintended effects](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2019-May/018351.html). So if you were relying on this, you still might *not* want to override the change in a `sudoers` file.

*See also [**WinEunuuchs2Unix's answer**](https://askubuntu.com/a/1047413/22949) to [Why should users never use normal sudo to start graphical applications?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications)*

---

### Why The Change

As [the changelog](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/eoan/+source/sudo/+changelog) puts it (under "sudo (1.8.27-1ubuntu2) eoan"):

> This restores sudo handling of $HOME to what everyone else does

"Everyone else" refers to the [upstream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstream_(software_development)) `sudo` project ([hosted here](https://www.sudo.ws/)) and also seemingly *all* other operating systems that contain `sudo`, except those that derive from Ubuntu.

There's more to it, though. This is also considered to fix a security bug, as described in [Ubuntu patch to add HOME to env_keep makes custom commands vulnerable by default](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1556302). The history was concisely summarized in [this comment there](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1556302/comments/3) by [Steve Langasek](https://launchpad.net/~vorlon) (whom [you may have heard of](https://raphaelhertzog.com/2011/05/06/people-behind-debian-steve-langasek-release-wizard/)), which I quote in full:

> This change was originally introduced in response to [bug #760140](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/760140).
>
> The upstream change in sudo was never accompanied by a CVE, and the behavior change was never applied to previous releases of Ubuntu, so it didn't seem security sensitive at the time.
>
> I am not opposed to changing this to behave the way Simon describes, but I defer to the Security Team here.

Todd C. Miller, [who maintains the upstream `sudo` project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo#History) (very actively, and for many years now), was also asked for input on the issue. He [explained the reason](https://www.sudo.ws/pipermail/sudo-users/2019-May/006223.html) `sudo` resets (i.e., does not preserve) `$HOME`:

> On Thu, 16 May 2019 07:48:40 -0400, Dan Streetman wrote:
>
> > I've cc'ed sudo-users, so the question to the upstream sudo list can
> >     be summarized as:
> >     How likely would it be for upstream sudo to add HOME to env_keep by default?
>
> Extremely unlikely.  Prior to sudo 1.7.4 the HOME and MAIL environment
>   variables were preserved in the environment by default.  This can
>   lead to programs using config files the original user's home
>   directory, which has security implications, so the default was
>   changed in 1.7.4.
>
> In the old days, sudo did little more than change the uid.  These
>   days sudo tries to run the command in an environment that closely
>   matches what you would get by logging in as that user.  This has
>   proven to be safer as it more closely matches the assumptions other
>   programs make.
>
> > We ask because Ubuntu carries a patch that adds HOME to env_keep,
> >     unlike the default upstream, or any other Linux/Unix.  We are
> >     considering removing that patch, to match upstream defaults, of *not*
> >     including HOME in env_keep.
>
> I would be supportive of that.  I believe that resetting HOME is
>   the safer default.
>
> - todd

(I have altered the formatting from [the original message](https://www.sudo.ws/pipermail/sudo-users/2019-May/006223.html) to display properly in this medium.)

As of 19.10, the [downstream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downstream_(software_development)) `sudo` in Ubuntu behaves as the upstream `sudo` (and `sudo` in other operating systems, including Debian) have behaved for many years. For more detailed information on the history of this change and the developments that preceded it, including numerous links for further reading, see the "`sudo` and `$HOME`: The Last 20 Years" section below.

### *Huh?* a.k.a. Why it (sometimes) matters what `sudo` does with `$HOME`

Programs you run that need the location of your [home directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory) often examine the value of the `$HOME` [environment variable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables). One important case is when a program tries to store and access [configuration files](https://askubuntu.com/a/1160765/22949) in the home directory of the user running it. Programs typically go by the value of `$HOME`. Sometimes when you run a program as a substitute user--for example, as the root account--it is appealing to have that program use *your* settings. But this can also get messy, in two ways:

1. Usually when you run a command as another user, you want it to work mostly the same way as if that user had run it. But if it is a command whose behavior can be radically altered by the fact that *you* ran it--which happens if its behavior is heavily customized by data read from files found inside the directory named in `$HOME`--then this goal is not achieved.

   When you're permitted to perform any action you choose as any user including root (which in Ubuntu is conferred by membership in the `sudo` group), the issue is mostly one of accident. However, if you are a limited user and you have been permitted to run *only specific commands* with `sudo`, then being able to manipulate what those commands do has serious security implications. [The bug report that led to the change in 19.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1556302) was specifically motivated by that problem (and includes [a compelling example of it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1556302/comments/4)).
2. If you run a command as another user and the command *makes changes* to its configuration in the directory named in `$HOME`, an attempt is made to write the changes to files in that location. When the substitute user is not root, as in `sudo -u username command`, this typically fails and produces error messages, which is mildly annoying but not serious.

   But in the common case that the substitute user is root, as in `sudo command`, this succeeds, but if any *new* files are created, they are owned by root, and your user account no longer has full access to all its own configuration files. This can be fixed by [`chown`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/chown.1.html)ing the files back, so the problem is most severe in the case of graphical applications, whose complexity can make it [so more files, in more places, are involved](https://askubuntu.com/a/1162664/22949) (and where it [has been reported](https://askubuntu.com/a/51573/22949) to sometimes [make login difficult](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop), though [usually the problem is less severe than that](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632798/what-specific-bad-things-happen-when-gedit-is-used-with-sudo)).

### What changed, and why all 19.10 systems have the change

A short whitelist of environment variables that are not reset by default is hard-coded in `sudo` itself. In Ubuntu releases prior to 19.10, [an Ubuntu-specific patch](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/tree/debian/patches/keep_home_by_default.patch?h=ubuntu/disco-security) adds `$HOME` to this whitelist. It is compiled into a binary file used by `sudo`, so upgrading to a version of `sudo` that does not have the patch removes it from the whitelist.

[The patch was removed in 19.10](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/eoan/+source/sudo/+changelog). So upgrading to 19.10 or higher will always apply the change, even when no *configuration files* associated with `sudo` are modified.

It is still possible to configure any version of `sudo` to preserve `$HOME` (see below). In the extremely unusual case that you did this before 19.10--when such a configuration would have made no difference--and kept that configuration across an upgrade, `$HOME` would still be preserved. But you would presumably remember having done this strange thing.

If your upgrade to 19.10 (or later) *failed* and gave you an only partially upgraded system with a version of `sudo` from before 19.10, then `sudo` on that system still preserves `$HOME` by default. This is almost the only case where `sudo` would preserve `$HOME` in 19.10 (or later) without you knowing about it--though you would still have been informed, during the release upgrade, that not all packages could be upgraded.

The easiest way to see directly that the patch is gone in the source code of `sudo` in Ubuntu 19.10 is to compare https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/tree/debian/patches?h=ubuntu/disco-security to https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/tree/debian/patches?h=ubuntu/eoan.

Still, if you are not sure how *your system* is configured, you can run `sudo printenv HOME` to find out.

### Resetting `$HOME` in Ubuntu 19.04 and earlier

Although updates to `sudo` in Ubuntu 19.04 and earlier may include changes to the *documentation* to explain the situation, the way `sudo` treats `$HOME` in those releases has not been and will not be changed by any updates. Most users will not want to bother manually changing how `sudo` works on systems where they are already using it without problems. However, if you like, you can make `sudo` reset `$HOME` on those systems, even without upgrading them.

**Any particular time you run `sudo`**, you can use the `-H`/`--set-home` option to reset `$HOME`:

```bash
sudo -H command
```

Or you can use `-i`. This does more than reset `$HOME`. `sudo -i command` behaves as if you logged in as root, ran *`command`*, and logged out; `sudo -i` by itself behaves as if you logged in as root and places you in an interactive root shell. This differs from `sudo -s`, which starts an interactive shell that is not a login shell. Before Ubuntu 19.10, `sudo -s` preserves `$HOME`; that is, regardless of version, the `-s` option does not carry any behavior that affects how `$HOME` is treated. It is meaningful to use `-H` and `-s` together. You can also use any of `-H`, `-i`, and `-s` with `-u user` to become *`user`* rather than root. Finally, using `sudo` via the graphical frontends `gksu` or `gksudo` (still available in 16.04 LTS, though you may need to install the `gksu` package) resets `$HOME`.

**If you want to reconfigure `sudo` so that it *always* resets `$HOME`**, you can enable the `always_set_home` option in a `sudoers` file:

```
Defaults    always_set_home
```

You would add that line to `/etc/sudoers` or, better, to a new file in `/etc/sudoers.d/`. Either way, you should use `visudo` to edit the file, so you get the benefit of syntax checking. (A syntax error in any `sudoers` file causes `sudo` to refuse to work at all. This is a hassle, though [it can be fixed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73864/how-to-modify-an-invalid-etc-sudoers-file).)

For example, on some of my pre-19.10 systems, I created and edited `/etc/sudoers.d/always_set_home` by running:

```bash
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/always_set_home
```

In the file, I wrote the above `Defaults` line. The filename need not be *`always_set_home`*--it can be whatever you like, so long as it contains no `.` or `~` character. The word on the `Defaults` line *does*, of course, need to be exactly `always_set_home`.

(One reason to prefer making a new file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` to modifying the existing `/etc/sudoers` file is that, if a future update ever *does* change the default `/etc/sudoers` file, you can accept the new file without losing your customizations. Another reason is that it is immediately clear that you have changed the configuration, and where your changes may be found.)

If you do this and later wish to run an individual `sudo` command that preserves `$HOME`, you can do that the same way you would do it in 19.10 (see below).

### Preserving `$HOME` in Ubuntu 19.10 and later

The way `sudo` treats `$HOME` has been changed for a reason. (See the above sections, as well as the detailed history section below.) But if you really want to make `sudo` continue to preserve `$HOME`, even in 19.10 and later, you can configure this behavior in a `sudoers` file.

**Any particular time you run `sudo`**, you can tell it to preserve `$HOME` with `--preserve-env=HOME`:

```bash
sudo --preserve-env=HOME command
```

This is the form of `--preserve-env` that is documented as `--preserve-env=list` in [the `sudo` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man8/sudo.8.html). It is also possible to use `--preserve-env` with no list operand, which is the same as `-E`; that preserves *all* environment variables. But there's rarely a good reason to do that, especially if your goal is just to preserve `$HOME`. If you don't like typing `--preserve-env=HOME`, you could define a shell alias or shell function or write a script that lets you run a shorter command to do it. Even better would be to seldom preserve `$HOME` (see the section below on alternatives to doing so).

More generally, you can make `sudo` preserve any particular environment variable *`varname`* with `--preserve-env=varname`. (You may also see code that effectively preserves `$HOME` by setting it explicitly in the command `sudo` runs, such as with `sudo HOME="$HOME" command`. This also works. It is quite different from `HOME="$HOME" sudo command`, which would not keep `sudo` from resetting `$HOME`.)

**Or if you *really* want to make `sudo` always preserve `$HOME`**, you can do this by adding `$HOME` to `env_keep` in a `sudoers` file:

```
Defaults    env_keep += "HOME"
```

That can go in `/etc/sudoers` or a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/`. Although I stress I don't recommend doing this at all, if you decide to do it then I'd suggest creating and editing `/etc/sudoers.d/keep-home` (call the file what you like, so long as the name doesn't contain `.` or `~`) by running:

```bash
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/keep-home
```

Then you can put that `Defaults` line in the file.

The reason to use `+=` instead of merely `=` is that there are a handful of other environment variables, hard-coded into `sudo` itself, that are preserved by default, and that you probably want preserved. If you used `=`, then *only* the environment variables you listed explicitly in the file would be preserved. In this case, that would be *just* `$HOME`. More information about the grammar of `sudoers` files is available in [sudoers(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man5/sudoers.5.html).

As for why I suggest making a file in `/etc/sudoers.d/` instead of editing `/etc/sudoers`--and why you should definitely use `visudo` either way--see my comments in the "Resetting `$HOME` in Ubuntu 19.04 and earlier" section above.

### Alternatives to Preserving `$HOME`

Most of the time you use `sudo`, the best alternative to preserving `$HOME` is to do nothing. Most `sudo` commands have the same effect (and some work slightly better) without `$HOME` preserved. However, I am aware of two popular use cases for preserving `$HOME`.

**Using your text editor configuration and/or plugins to edit files owned by root or another user.** `sudoedit`, or equivalently `sudo -e`, is an ideal alternative for this. It runs the editor as *you*, you edit a temporary copy of the file, and the file is updated when you quit the editor. Since the editor runs as you, it uses your configuration and plugins automatically, and does so without any risk of failing in opaque and unexpected ways with permission denied errors or making files in your home directory inaccessible to you. To edit *`file`*:

```bash
sudoedit file
```

To edit *`file`* with **`editor`** instead of the default editor:

```bash
SUDO_EDITOR=editor sudoedit file
```

For example, `SUDO_EDITOR=vim sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list` edits `/etc/apt/sources.list` with `vim`.

To decide what editor to use, `sudoedit` consults the [environment variable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) `$SUDO_EDITOR`; if that's unset, it consults `$VISUAL`; if that's unset, it consults `$EDITOR`; if that's unset, it tries editor commands from a hard-coded list, which in practice in Ubuntu means it uses `editor`. Typically that resolves to `/usr/bin/editor`, which is a symlink. If you want to change the default editor *systemwide* then you can change what `/usr/bin/editor` points to by running `sudo update-alternatives --config editor`. [You can also set](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Session-wide_environment_variables) one of those three environment variables, which is a good way to change what `sudoedit` edits with for just one user.

**Making programs you *only* run as root use specific configuration files.** If a program you run as root looks in `$HOME` for its configuration, then you can just put that configuration in (or move that configuration to) root's home directory, `/root`.

### Resetting `$HOME` when you don't know what release you're using

You may sometimes write a command and not know what release of Ubuntu (or what operating systems besides Ubuntu) it will run on. For example, you may be writing a script that you will run on multiple machines.

`sudo` continues to accept the `-H` option, with the same effect it always had. It just happens that, starting on 19.10, `sudo` without `-H` does the same thing (unless you have configured it to do otherwise) as `sudo -H`.

To write portable `sudo` commands that reset `$HOME`, you can continue using:

```
sudo -H command
```

(Also as before, if all the actions performed in your script need to be done as root, it's probably better not to use `sudo` in your script and just run the script as root with `sudo`.)

### `sudo` and `$HOME`: The Last 20 Years

[Around the turn of the century](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/rev/c2f97651db4c), the [upstream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstream_(software_development)) `sudo` project introduced the `env_reset` option, which makes `sudo` reset most environment variables. This option is enabled unless disabled explicitly in a `sudoers` file. (It is possible to enable it explicitly, which `Defaults env_reset` in Debian and Ubuntu's `/etc/sudoers` file does, but this is not actually necessary.) Before `sudo` had `env_reset`, all environment variables were preserved unchanged. With `env_reset`, only a handful of variables were preserved. This included `$HOME`.

[In July of 2010](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/rev/f421f8827340), `$HOME` was removed from that small whitelist and thus no longer preserved by default.

[In September of 2010](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=596847), a bug report about documenting that in the `sudo` package in Debian was filed. As far as I can tell, there was no controversy about, or objection to, the change itself, from Debian developers. (But see below.)

[In February of 2011](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2011-February/032487.html), the change had come further [downstream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downstream_(software_development)) from Debian to Ubuntu and Ubuntu developers discussed whether or not it was desirable.

[In April of 2011](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/760140), the change was reported as a bug, referencing that discussion. (Some behavior resulting from the change [had been reported as a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/759019) the day before that.) At least at the time, this was [considered](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/760140/comments/2) to be a [regression](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/41095/14778) ("the Debian maintainer already tried to fix this once but it appears the fix was incomplete"). I haven't found any such Debian bug report, but that doesn't mean there wasn't one; furthermore, a change could have been made without one. I suspect, though, that it *may* have been an erroneous reference to [that documentation bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=596847).

[The next day](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/760140/comments/5), the development release of Ubuntu was updated with a downstream, Ubuntu-only patch, to re-add `$HOME` to the list of environment variables `sudo` preserved by default. I believe this was done quickly so as to make it into the release of Ubuntu 11.04. The effect was that `sudo` in 11.04, as in previous Ubuntu releases, preserved `$HOME` by default.

[In November of 2011](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/889936), a bug was reported about how the documentation for `sudo` in Ubuntu said `$HOME` was reset. That is, the manpage in Ubuntu correctly described the behavior of upstream `sudo` but not the patched behavior in Ubuntu.

[In September of 2014](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1373495), a bug was reported pointing out some of the problems with having `sudo` preserve `$HOME` by default and arguing that the problem with running graphical programs with normal `sudo` is not that it's inherently dangerous (often cited to [this wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo)) but that `sudo`'s *unusual handling of `$HOME` in Ubuntu* makes it dangerous and should be considered a bug. It appears there was significant interest in this bug report, including from Ubuntu developers, even though it would be some time before it would be fixed.

[In March of 2016](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1556302), the bug that would later become the main reference for the problems with `sudo` preserving `$HOME` was reported. Initially, this bug report focused specifically on the security problem that users who are not administrators (i.e., cannot run arbitrary commands as root), but who have been permitted to run *specific* commands with `sudo`, can maliciously alter the behavior of some programs, and in some cases even gain full control of the system. It recommended a narrow change that would attempt to address that case specifically, while still having `$HOME` preserved when members of the `sudo` group run commands as root or another user.

[In April of 2019](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1823202), a bug was reported objecting to the behavior of `sudo` preserving `$HOME` by default, even when `sudo -s` is used.

[Later that month](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1556302/comments/7), discussion resumed on the [March 2016 bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1556302), toward the possible resolution of removing the Ubuntu-specific patch altogether. This broadened the focus of that bug report beyond the specific security vulnerability it described. The goal of making `sudo` in Ubuntu treat `$HOME` the same way upstream `sudo` (and `sudo` in other operating systems) treats it, starting in Ubuntu 19.10, was articulated.

[In May of 2019](https://bugs.launchpad.net/launchpadlib/+bug/1828208), a bug was reported about how programs (including non-graphical programs) that use launchpadlib suffer configuration file ownership problems because `sudo` preserves `$HOME`.

[A week later](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2019-May/018345.html), another mailing list discussion on "how sudo handles $HOME" took place (see also [this archive page](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2019-May/thread.html#18345)), showcasing a range of views on how `sudo` ought to treat `$HOME`. One preference that was uncontroversial was that [*if* a change were to be made, it should only be to 19.10 and later](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2019-May/018347.html), and not be made in any [updates for previous releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates). The [question arose](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2019-May/018348.html) of whether upstream `sudo` would continue resetting `$HOME` in future versions.

The [upstream `sudo` maintainer](https://www.sudo.ws/todd/todd.html), when [consulted about this](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2019-May/018350.html), made clear that [no such upstream change is planned](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2019-May/018355.html) and supported the view that the downstream version of `sudo` in Ubuntu should also reset `$HOME` by default. That message, posted originally [on the sudo-users mailing list](https://www.sudo.ws/pipermail/sudo-users/2019-May/006223.html), was [quoted in a comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1556302/comments/13) on [the March 2016 bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1556302).

[In June 2019](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1556302/comments/15), Ubuntu developers made plans to remove the patch that makes `sudo` in Ubuntu preserve `$HOME`.

[About a week later](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/+bug/1556302/comments/16), the change was made in Ubuntu's repositories. This change applies starting in 19.10. The only change that will be made to `sudo` in earlier releases is to update the documentation so it clearly and correctly describes the behavior of `sudo` in those releases.

### Acknowledgements

- [Zanna](https://askubuntu.com/users/527764/zanna) helped me figure out what this should cover and how to cover it, and she gave feedback on multiple fragments and drafts of it as I wrote them (see conversation [back then](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/66387?m=51118652#51118652), [more recently starting here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/66387?m=52250602#52250602), then [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/66387?m=52304118#52304118), [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/66387?m=52366441#52366441), [there](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/66387?m=52408066#52408066), and finally [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/66387?m=52466558#52466558) and [there](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52468999#52468999)).
- [Seth](https://askubuntu.com/users/44179/seth) and [DK Bose](https://askubuntu.com/users/248158/dk-bose) encouraged me to write this (see conversation around [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=52231454#52231454) and [there](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/201?m=52231625#52231625)).
- [WinEunuuchs2Unix](https://askubuntu.com/users/307523/wineunuuchs2unix) wrote [that excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1047413/22949) and [expanded it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1047413/revisions) to cover how `sudo` changed in 19.10, which preceded this Q&A and (as far as I know) was the first information about the change posted to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: +1's for your excellent Q&A. I don't really deserve first answer kudos because my answer was inspired by your comments about `sudo` changes in the Ask Ubuntu general chatroom.

Comment: I created `sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/keep-home` with `Defaults    env_keep += "HOME"` per your instructions, thanks!

Comment: I think it is worth to mention this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20504662/how-to-get-home-directory-of-different-user-in-bash-script
You can create something like `SUDO_HOME=\`eval echo "~$SUDO_USER"\``

Comment: Another reason to preserve `$HOME`, albeit minor and there are better ways to handle this: I was using a custom terminal profile located in `~./terminfo/x`, and since my home directory was logged down `0700`, when running commands like `sudo systemctl status a-service` when `TERM=x-my-cutsom-profile`, then `systemctl` would complain about a not fully functional terminal. The _best_ solution here is to just put the terminfo file in expected system locations--but I don't own this particular box.