# Why on Ubuntu 18.04 command "sudo -u username -s" not works as on CentOS 7?

Tags: sudo, home-directory, su

I want to use a system user to separate permissions when I run nodejs scripts.

I created `node-user`:

```
sudo useradd -r -m node-user
```

Then I expected that next command login me in shell `node-user`:

```
sudo -u node-user -s
```

But seems that it's uses my var environment:

```
node-user@host:~$ echo $HOME
> /home/me
```

Why? On CentOS 7 it's print `/home/node-user`.

I know that I can to set password for `node-user` and login like this:

```
su - node-user
```

But for me it's not logical, because `node-user` it's system user and may not have a password.

Comment: Related, I think: [How does sudo handle $HOME differently since 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186999/how-does-sudo-handle-home-differently-since-19-10/1187000#1187000)

Comment: @steeldriver, thank you! I resolved my problem, and now I can `sudo -H -u node-user -s` and all works fine.