# In 20.04 "sudo -s" no longer utilizes user's ".config/*" files?

Tags: 18.04, sudo, 20.04

I have an [htop](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/htop.1.html) config in `/etc/skel/.config/htop/htoprc` copied to all new user  home directories. When I run [htop](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/htop.1.html) as a regular user I see the expected settings. However under 18.04 if I ran `sudo -s` then [htop](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/htop.1.html) Ubuntu would still use my regular user's htoprc from `.config` and work fine.

On 20.04 I notice when I `sudo -s` then `htop` it is no longer reads the user's config from their shell, it creates a new file in `/root/.config/htop/htoprc` with default htop settings. Is this something new about [how sudo works in Focal](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/sudo.8.html)? I thought the `-s` would keep utilizing the calling users shell as opposed to `-i` which switches to the root user's shell?

Comment: Related: [How does sudo handle $HOME differently since 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186999/how-does-sudo-handle-home-differently-since-19-10)