# How to install topspin 4.1.4 in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: software-installation

I am new to Ubuntu and I am having trouble to set up a software called Topspin in my computer. I followed the instructions from this previous post [how to install topspin 4.08 in ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246691/how-to-install-topspin-4-08-in-ubuntu-19-10) . However, when I try the last step that involves the following piece of code:

```
# pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY topspin-4.1.4-linux.sh
```

It returns

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘topspin-4.1.4-linux.sh’: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: The system tells you it cannot find the file ‘topspin-4.1.4-linux.sh’.  So, either you do not have it or it is located in another directory than the current one.  Could you check?

Comment: Hi, yes I am in the correct directory. I can try to open the file by entering: 
"./topspin-4.1.4-linux.sh" and fails to install. This is expected according to the previous post. That is why they add the he command "# pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY". However when I add  it  gives the message "/usr/bin/env: ‘topspin-4.1.4-linux.sh’: No such file or directory"

Comment: why are you using `env`? That doesn't do what you probably think it does.  `env` is used to use an Environment Variable or the current system / runtime environment to resolve the path for a program to use when it's different than pure system installed versions - i.e. `/usr/bin/env python3` inside a venv for Python uses the virtualenv's python, but outside of that env on the bare system it's `/usr/bin/python3`.  What's your intention with using `env`, to declare env variables?

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path:

```
# pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY `pwd`/topspin-4.1.4-linux.sh
```

Comment: Please remember the Code of Conduct when formulating your answers: https://askubuntu.com/conduct