# Trouble getting chromium-browser to run successfully on Ubuntu v20.04

Tags: permissions, configuration, chromium, snap

I had initially created a couple of directories in `/home`, which got filled with the content of previously successful work dirs. Consequently, enabling me to `try/test/adapt` one, and continue on; moving quickly... I settled on one, left the `softlink` coupled to the chosen dir, and since have installed all manners of working application/drivers/etc from the `"Ux Repository"` via Synaptic, to date; including Firefox & Chrome.

Today, I found it necessary to install another valued browser (Chromium), only to end up with error message result indicated below. One can also note that every other install was able to set up, and leave it's config stuff in it's `~/.config` dir. Thus, I find it frustrating to note that there does not exist a `~/.config/[cC]hromium[-browser]` directory there, as well?

Moreover, Chromium also should not need fail in such a manner, as the dir that it claims to have trouble creating, already exists, and is usable?  So, is there an existing modification/code addition that I might be able to apply, to enable proper execution with this described setup; other than creating a `"odoncaoaB"` user, and su'ing to it in order to make use of Chromium every time hereafter? Cheers odoncaoa

```
/home/odoncaoa 2020-06-09 13:49
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[27]$ **chromium-browser**
2020/06/09 13:50:33.298865 cmd_run.go:563: WARNING: XAUTHORITY environment value is not a clean path: "/home/odoncaoaB/.Xauthority"
cannot create user data directory: /home/odoncaoa/snap/chromium/1182: Not a directory

/home/odoncaoa 2020-06-09 14:06
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[41]$ **cd ..; ll**
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root     4096 Apr 12 14:48 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root     root     4096 Feb 28 22:01 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root     root        9 Mar  5 14:47 odoncaoa -> odoncaoaB
drwxr-xr-x 17 odoncaoa users    4096 Mar  5 14:46 odoncaoa_
drwxr-xr-x 39 odoncaoa odoncaoa 4096 Jun  9 13:12 odoncaoaB
drwxrwxr-x  2 u0_a239  u0_a239  4096 Apr 12 14:48 u0_a239

/home/odoncaoa 2020-06-09 15:21
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[41]$ **l .config**
 ./                  deluge/                google-chrome/   mpv/               user-dirs.dirs
 ../                 enchant/               gtk-2.0/         nemo/              user-dirs.locale
 atril/              epiphany/              gtk-3.0/         obs-studio/        vlc/
 autostart/          filemanager-actions/   ibus/            pcmanfm/           xfce4/
 celluloid/          FreeFileSync/          libfm/           pulse/             yelp/
 cinnamon-layout/    gedit/                 libreoffice/     QtProject.conf
 cinnamon-session/   GIMP/                  lxterminal/      rtorrent/
'Code Industry'/     gmpc/                  menus/           streamtuner2/
 dconf/              goa-1.0/               mimeapps.list    update-notifier/

/home/odoncaoa 2020-06-09 14:02
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[36]$ **grep odoncaoa /etc/passwd**
odoncaoa:x:1000:100:Douglas Randall:/home/odoncaoa:/bin/bash

home/odoncaoaB 2020-06-09 16:08
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[49]$ **grep users /etc/group**
users:x:100:odoncaoa

/home/odoncaoa 2020-06-09 14:25
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[49]$ **which chromium-browser**
/usr/bin/chromium-browser

/home/odoncaoa 2020-06-09 14:26
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[50]$ **file /usr/bin/chromium-browser**
/usr/bin/chromium-browser: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable

/home/odoncaoa 2020-06-09 14:05
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[39]$ **set | grep 'odoncaoa'**
HOME=/home/odoncaoa
XAUTHORITY=/home/odoncaoa/.Xauthority

home/odoncaoaB 2020-06-09 16:24
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[52]$ **cat .Xauthority | od -c**
0000000 001  \0  \0  \n   t   u   f   F   X   7   0   5   d   u  \0 001
0000020   0  \0 022   M   I   T   -   M   A   G   I   C   -   C   O   O
0000040   K   I   E   -   1  \0 020 326 257 220 035 035 277   e 016  \a
0000060 275 336   / 221 321 035   8
0000067

/home/odoncaoa 2020-06-09 13:52
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[40]$ **find $HOME/snap -print**
/home/odoncaoa/snap
/home/odoncaoa/snap/gnome-system-monitor
/home/odoncaoa/snap/gnome-system-monitor/current
/home/odoncaoa/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common
/home/odoncaoa/snap/gnome-system-monitor/127
/home/odoncaoa/snap/chromium
/home/odoncaoa/snap/chromium/current
/home/odoncaoa/snap/chromium/common
/home/odoncaoa/snap/chromium/1182
/home/odoncaoa/snap/chromium/1165

/home/odoncaoa 2020-06-09 15:20
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[39]$ **ll snap/ch***
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 5 odoncaoa odoncaoa 4096 Jun  9 12:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 odoncaoa odoncaoa 4096 Mar 20 13:31 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 odoncaoa odoncaoa 4096 Mar 20 13:31 1165
drwxr-xr-x 2 odoncaoa odoncaoa 4096 Mar 20 13:31 1182
drwxr-xr-x 2 odoncaoa odoncaoa 4096 Mar 20 13:31 common
lrwxrwxrwx 1 odoncaoa users       4 Jun  9 12:57 current -> 1182

/home 2020-06-09 14:08
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[41]$ **set | grep 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR'**
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000

/home 2020-06-09 14:16
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[44]$ **ll /run/user**
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root    60 Jun  9 13:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 35 root     root  1000 Jun  9 13:19 ..
drwx------ 11 odoncaoa users  360 Jun  9 13:19 1000

/home/odoncaoaB 2020-06-09 16:24
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[53]$ **l /run/user/1000**
./    dbus-1/  gvfs/          keyring/            .portals-unavailable         speech-dispatcher/
../   dconf/   ICEauthority   pcmanfm-socket--0=  pulse/                       systemd/
bus=  gnupg/   inaccessible/  pk-debconf-socket=  snapd-session-agent.socket=  update-notifier.pid

/home 2020-06-09 14:16
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[46]$ **ll /run/user/1000**
total 4
drwx------ 11 odoncaoa users 360 Jun  9 13:19 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root     root   60 Jun  9 13:12 ..
srw-rw-rw-  1 odoncaoa users   0 Jun  9 13:12 bus
drwx------  3 odoncaoa users  60 Jun  9 13:12 dbus-1
drwx------  2 odoncaoa users  60 Jun  9 13:12 dconf
drwx------  2 odoncaoa users 140 Jun  9 13:12 gnupg
dr-x------  2 odoncaoa users   0 Jun  9 13:12 gvfs
-rw-------  1 odoncaoa users 334 Jun  9 13:12 ICEauthority
d---------  3 odoncaoa users 160 Jun  9 13:12 inaccessible
drwx------  2 odoncaoa users 100 Jun  9 13:12 keyring
srwxr-xr-x  1 odoncaoa users   0 Jun  9 13:12 pcmanfm-socket--0
srw-rw-rw-  1 odoncaoa users   0 Jun  9 13:12 pk-debconf-socket
-rw-r--r--  1 odoncaoa users   0 Jun  9 13:19 .portals-unavailable
drwx------  2 odoncaoa users  80 Jun  9 13:12 pulse
srw-rw-rw-  1 odoncaoa users   0 Jun  9 13:12 snapd-session-agent.socket
drwx------  4 odoncaoa users 100 Jun  9 13:12 speech-dispatcher
drwxr-xr-x  4 odoncaoa users 120 Jun  9 13:12 systemd
-rw-------  1 odoncaoa users   0 Jun  9 13:13 update-notifier.pid

/home/odoncaoa 2020-06-09 15:16
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[35]$ **ll Desktop/chr* /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop**
-rwxr--r-- 1 odoncaoa users    12478 Jun  9 15:14 Desktop/chromium-browser.desktop
-rwxr-xr-x 1 odoncaoa odoncaoa 12933 Mar  5 18:52 Desktop/chromium_chromium.desktop
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     12478 Oct 22  2019 /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop


/home/odoncaoaB 2020-06-09 16:53
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[57]$ **cd /snap**

/snap 2020-06-09 16:53
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[58]$ **l**
./  ../  bin/  chromium/  core18/  gtk-common-themes/  README  snapd/

/snap 2020-06-09 16:53
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[59]$ **ll**
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Mar  5 18:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root 4096 Feb 28 22:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Jun  8 09:57 bin
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Jun  8 09:57 chromium
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Apr 30 12:33 core18
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Apr 21 15:05 gtk-common-themes
-r--r--r--  1 root root  548 Mar  5 13:46 README
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Jun  3 14:11 snapd

/snap 2020-06-09 16:53
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[60]$ **l bin**
./  ../  chromium@  chromium.chromedriver@

/snap 2020-06-09 16:54
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[61]$ **l s*d**
./  ../  7264/  7777/  current@
```

Comment: /root 17:23
root@tufFX705du# l
./   .bash_history  .cache/   .dbus/  .local/         .profile  .synaptic/  .wget-hsts
../  .bashrc        .config/  .inxi/  .multibootusb/  snap/     .viminfo

/root 17:23
root@tufFX705du# l snap
./  ../  chromium/

/root 17:24
root@tufFX705du# l snap/chromium
./  ../  1182/  common/  current@

Comment: /root 17:31
root@tufFX705du# l .config
./  ../  gtk-3.0/  ibus/  QtProject.conf

Comment: /root 17:34
root@tufFX705du# l snap/chromium/1182
./   .config/  Documents/  .last_revision  Music/     Public/     .themes@
../  Desktop/  Downloads/  .local/         Pictures/  Templates/  Videos/

Comment: /home/odoncaoa 2020-06-09 17:43
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[46]$ ps -eaf | grep -i snap
root        1031       1  0 13:12 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
odoncaoa   11017    1980  0 17:43 pts/1    00:00:00 grep -i snap

Comment: /home/odoncaoa 2020-06-09 17:43
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[47]$ l /usr/lib/snapd
./           snap-bootstrap*  snapd.core-fixup.sh*  snap-failure*   snap-seccomp*
../          snap-confine*    snap-device-helper*   snap-gdb-shim*  snap-update-ns*
complete.sh  snapctl*         snap-discard-ns*      snap-mgmt*      system-shutdown*
etelpmoc.sh  snapd*           snapd.run-from-snap*  snap-preseed*
info         snapd-apparmor*  snap-exec*            snap-repair*

/home/odoncaoa 2020-06-09 17:45
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[50]$ cat /usr/lib/snapd/info
VERSION=2.44.3+20.04

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Ubuntu BASH had been changed, way back when, to be able to 
handle (at least) the scenario that I previously described, for try/test
/adapt other system useful working user files, via softling use. But, as
 it turns out, the adaptation turned out to be a shell functional 
divergence (as compared to every behavior of every other shell's 
functionality), and the adaptation managed to cause headaches throughout 
the [Lin,U]nix universe, until Ubuntu v19.10. Read about the change that 
was made, and a tad regarding historical perms issues here:

```
https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-
        normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications/1047413#1047413
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186999/how-does-sudo-handle-home-
        differently-since-19-10
```

And, as can be seen, with a few minor corrections the latest system, 
snap, chromium, and any/every other application introduced, and made 
available for execution upon/within an Ubuntu 19.10+ system, will do so, 
and be able to count on the permission behavior regarding the user 
execution enviromnent (via BASH), be the same as execution via any other 
shell present within the global user code base.

Below, note I went ahead, bit my tongue, and did create a 'odoncaoaB' 
user via /etc/profile & /etc/group. And, su'd to the user, and retried 
the troubled command (chromium-browser). Still no joy; but the error 
output was far different, and all had to do with permissions!? The fix 
following, indicates the change made, and life normality has, once again, 
been restored!
Cheers, odoncaoa

---

/home/odoncaoaB 2020-06-10 11:06
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[1]$ **sudo -u odoncaoaB bash**
[sudo] password for odoncaoa: 
===> BINDIR     was not set!! <==
BINDIR  =   /usr/local/BinDrD
===> 75.        =       $SHELLX='bash'

/home/odoncaoaB 2020-06-10 11:42
odoncaoaB@tufFX705du[1]$ **chromium-browser**
mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium
/1182/.config': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/1182/.local': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/common/.cache': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/run/user/1002': Permission denied
Can't create dir /home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/1182/Desktop
Can't create dir /home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/1182/Downloads
Can't create dir /home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/1182/Templates
Can't create dir /home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/1182/Public
Can't create dir /home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/1182/Documents
Can't create dir /home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/1182/Music
Can't create dir /home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/1182/Pictures
Can't create dir /home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/1182/Videos
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
realpath: '': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium
/1182/.config’: Permission denied
/snap/chromium/1182/bin/desktop-launch: line 410: /home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/1182/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf: No such file or
 directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium
/1182/.local/share': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium
/1182/.themes': Permission denied
/snap/chromium/1182/bin/desktop-launch: line 504: /home/odoncaoaB
/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gdk-pixbuf-loaders.cache: No such file or 
directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/common
/.cache’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium
/1182/.local’: Permission denied
ln: target '/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-modules' is
 not a directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium
/1182/.local’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium
/1182/.config’: Permission denied
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium
/1182/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/1182/.config’: Permission denied
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/1182/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium
/1182/.config’: Permission denied
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/1182/.config/gtk-2.0/gtkfilechooser.ini': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/1182/.config’: Permission denied
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium
/1182/.config/ibus': No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/common
/.cache’: Permission denied
ln: target '/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/common/.cache/immodules' is not 
a directory
/snap/chromium/1182/bin/desktop-launch: line 580: /home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/common/.cache/immodules/immodules.cache: No such file or 
directory
/snap/chromium/1182/bin/desktop-launch: line 591: /home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/1182/.last_revision: Permission denied
Unable to open directory /home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/common/.cache/gio-
modules: Error opening directory “/home/odoncaoaB/snap/chromium/common
/.cache/gio-modules”: No such file or directory
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)

---

/home 2020-06-10 12:01
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[15]$ **sudo rm odoncaoa; mv odoncaoaB odoncaoa;
 chgrp -R odoncaoa users**

/home 2020-06-10 12:02
odoncaoa@tufFX705du[16]$ **ll**
total 20
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root    4096 Jun 10 12:02 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root     root    4096 Feb 28 22:01 ..
drwxr-xr-x 39 odoncaoa users   4096 Jun 10 11:05 odoncaoa
drwxr-xr-x 17 odoncaoa users   4096 Mar  5 14:46 odoncaoa_
drwxrwxr-x  2 u0_a239  u0_a239 4096 Apr 12 14:48 u0_a239