# What makes "~" under sudo change between different installations?

Tags: bash, permissions, sudo

I have two computers.  One, Computer A, runs Ubuntu 18.04.  The other, Computer B, runs Ubuntu 20.04.

On Computer A, I have a `~/.bash_aliases` file

```
-rw-r--r--    userA    userA    /home/userA/.bash_aliases
```

with the following aliases:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
alias runtest='$HOME/bin/test_script.sh'
```

The `~/bin/test_script.sh` file

```
-rwxr--r--    userA    userA    /home/userA/bin/test_script.sh
```

has the contents

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ~
```

When I run the alias as both `userA` and `root`, I get

```
$ runtest
/home/userA
$ sudo runtest
/home/userA
```

(which is what I want, for what it's worth).

On computer B, I'm trying to make an identical setup.  The `~/.bash_aliases` file

```
-rw-r--r--    userB    groupB    /home/userB/.bash_aliases
```

has the same aliases

```
alias sudo='sudo '
alias runtest='$HOME/bin/test_script.sh'
```

The script `~/bin/test_script.sh`

```
-rwxr--r--    userB    groupB    /home/userB/bin/test_script.sh
```

has the exact same contents as on Computer A.  On Computer B, however, running the alias as both `userA` and `root` gives different results:

```
$ runtest
/home/userB
$ sudo runtest
/root
```

Notice that when executing `$ sudo runtest`, `~` is interpreted as the `$HOME` folder of the user (`userA`) on Computer A, but the `$HOME` folder of `root` on Computer B.  I would like it to return `/home/userB`, just as it does on Computer A.

Things I've checked:

- I have sourced `.bash_aliases` on both machines since last editing them.
- `/etc/sudoers` is identical on both computers, and neither has `env_keep` set anywhere within `/etc/sudoers.d/`.
- `/etc/pam.conf` and `/etc/pam.d/sudo` are identical on both computers.
- The `$PATH` values are identical for both users and for both roots, respectively.

For the users:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/user(A|B)/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

For `root` on both Computer A and Computer B:

```
$ sudo su
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

There must be something different between the two computers, but I've checked everything I know to check.  What else could explain the different behavior?  Did something change between 18.04 and 20.04 that would affect this?

Comment: echo $PATH .. /home/user(A|B) ... literally or is it implied userA and userB

Comment: Possibly related: [How does sudo handle $HOME differently since 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1186999/how-does-sudo-handle-home-differently-since-19-10)

Comment: @bac0n Not literally, no.  It's `/home/userA` for the first case, `/home/userB` for the other.

Comment: @steeldriver That seems like it describes the issue exactly.  I'll start reading through it.  Thanks!