# Is the Ubuntu community wiki entry on RootSudo current?

Tags: ubuntu-wiki

*Note: This has been resolved. The source isn't current for my purposes, so I'm dismissing it.*

I was looking for a source about the superuser and came across [this entry](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) from the community wiki.

The entry has the following disclaimer at the top:

> **March 14, 2019. PLEASE NOTE: This wiki article is being significantly rewritten as it contains a good deal of old, dated, and possibly questionable material. Using caution and consulting with others on the Ubuntu Forums or Ask Ubuntu is highly recommended!**

The source looks like what I was looking for. However, if it's not current, it's of no use to me.

Could anyone tell me whether this entry is current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of it is OK, there are bits and parts that might be outdated (but not less safe). For example, Ubuntu stopped patching `sudo`'s default of resetting `HOME` ([How does sudo handle $HOME differently since 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1186999/158442)), so now:

- `HOME` in `sudo bash` should be `/root`, and
- You don't need to use `-H` anymore (because it's redundant).

Otherwise, very little has changed in `sudo` for good advice on it to change that often.

Comment: That means that the source as a whole is no longer current, so I'll dismiss it.

Thank you for your elaborate response in any case!

Answer (score 7):

Looks good (from a user standpoint) to me. I'm a long-time `sudo` user, and nothing seemed bogus.

But, one should treat all information from "the Internet" with a certain degree of suspicion.

Comment: According to muru and the source he cited, some parts of the entry are outdated, so I'm dismissing it.

I appreciate your comment, though. Especially what you said about being skeptical.