# World of Warcraft on PlayOnLinux: graphics problem

Tags: 11.10, intel-graphics, playonlinux

I have an HP 430 and `lshw -c video` command line said:

```
 *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:42 memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
**WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.**
```

I'm running this at Ubuntu Oneiric Ocelot 11.10 and PlayOnLinux 4.0.12.

[image]

Comment: This is a bug report.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please install **mesa-utils** if not yet installed: `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils` to test for OpenGL support.

Run a check to see if you have OpenGL support: `glxinfo|grep 'direct rendering'` or `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p`.

And run `glxgears` to see how your video card renders and its FPS for the render.

If it appears you have OpenGL support and all is good then add to the WoW launcher the **-opengl** parameter. For example `'.wine/drive_c/Program Files/World of Warcraft/Wow.exe' -opengl`

and test to see the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot!. The only thing that I must fix, is that the trees are black pixelated =(. By the way, which is the optimal FPS I should have?

Comment: For the human Eye the optimal is above 29 FPS. Less than that and you will visually see "lag". To lower this, add the -console parameter to your wow link and when inside wow press the ` symbol next to the 1. Then type farclip 100. farclip is how far you see objects, textures, landscape, etc.. It ranges from 100 to 2590. Farclip 100 is the best to start tunning the video. Please also read here to educate about the correct use of wine and maybe some helpful tips to improve the performance: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66980/problems-running-a-windows-app-in-wine