# How stable is wow on linux?

Tags: graphics, wine, games

Hi I have a very simple question for anyone who has played wow on Linux. The title says it all but how is wow on Linux running wine.

Comment: Hi John, please red the FAQ to better enhance your question here: http://askubuntu.com/faq

Answer (score 4):

WoW 4.3 is rated Platinum on the Wine Application Database, located [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/).

Platinum means it runs without any issues...

Answer (score 1):

I can say that I have tested WoW on Linux with Wine and PlayOnLinux, and since 3.3.5 the version has been fast and stable. It is platinum as you can see in this link:

http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1922

It will work out of the box with the downloadable installer or DVDs. Everything works great but you need to consider some minor details. For example, since Cataclysm (Versions 4.x) some of the video effects will not work 100%. They will just appear disable as you will see on the links I post below.

I recommend just to be sure to read one of my answers about wow:

[World of Warcraft on PlayOnLinux: graphics problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66959/world-of-wacraft-on-playonlinux-graphics-problem/66970#66970) - Helps to install tools to test GLX performance and support.

[Gaming performance difference between Windows and Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163903/gaming-performance-difference-between-windows-7-and-ubuntu/163931#163931) - A small continuous study I have conducted over the performance of games in Ubuntu with Wine and how they have improved over time.

[Shader Model 3.0 not recognized in Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102710/shader-model-3-0-not-recognized-in-wine) - Shader Moderl 3.0 support found on Wow Cataclysm 4.x and how it will affect WoW users in Ubuntu (This will be updated when Wine has full support for it). Note that this does not have a lower performance, it just means that Shader 3.x is not supported yet.

[Adjusting resolution for individual Wine programs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16733/adjusting-resolution-for-individual-wine-programs) - Wine configuration for better play-ability.