# Compatibility program?

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15518/how-do-i-install-wine)

I am new to Ubuntu and have 11.10. Really need to install a program I use all the time on a Windows 7 desktop.

Is it possible to use a windows required program on Ubuntu and if so what so I have to do to make that possible?

Comment: Depends on the program. In general, Linux (Ubuntu) is not a drop in replacement for windows. Your options are finding a linux alternate, Wine, Virtualization (KVM / Virtualbox), and dual booting. You can check your application here: http://appdb.winehq.org/

Comment: Could you tell us what program it is you want to use? Maybe there is a good alternative you can use

Answer (score 1):

- If your program is written in Java, Python, Perl, Ruby, Smalltalk and many more, there should be no problem.
- [Many programs run in Wine (Wine Is No Emulator)](http://appdb.winehq.org/)
- Or you setup a virtual machine like KVM, Virtualbox, VMware
- Or you dualboot
- Or you give us the name, and we try finding a good replacement