# Is Wine what I think it is?

Tags: wine, performance

My first impression is that Wine is a simulated Windows environment which uses free (and presumably open source) libraries as an alternative to Microsoft's proprietary libraries. Those libraries produce the same input and output, yet use alternative means to process the data. This would explain why there is very little performance hit.

Is my impression of WHAT exactly Wine is correct?

Has anyone noticed a performance loss from Wine (relative to actual Windows)?

Comment: You ask the same question as the duplicate except, you provide an answer and ask is your answer correct. As far as performance loss question goes, it should be a separate question if at all. Your last sentence of the first para notes there is very little performance hit. Then you ask for other's opinions. AFIK seeking opinion is off topic. I am not saying there is no value added. The two questions should be merged.