# How do I run "HP Support Assistant"?

Tags: wine, hp

Battery performance on my hp-laptop has degraded in a disastrous way.

HP will only replace the battery if I give them the result from their "HP support Assistant " software. I downloaded the software and tried to run the same with "Wine". Neither didn't it got installed nor did it throw any exception.

Ubuntu Software center doesn't have the software, is there a way to convert the software into deb format for install on ubuntu.

---

Edit 1:- On installing with wine, i get the following error:-

```
ankit@stream:~/.wine/drive_c/swsetup/SP54620$ wine  msiinstaller.exe 
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
fixme:apphelp:ApphelpCheckInstallShieldPackage stub: 0x32d5fc L"C:\\users\\Public\\Application Data\\{A8DA1505-E615-42BB-BB77-74D5CC91FE7E}\\HP Support Assistant.msi"
ankit@stream:~/.wine/drive_c/swsetup/SP54620$
```

Comment: What is the specific wording of your warranty/guarantee? Read it. Review the [consumer rights for your country](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumer_Protection_Act_of_1986). Exercise them. Don't be so quick to accept HP's decision. Companies do this a lot and are often bluffing. If you are **certain** the battery is bad, escalate. Send a letter making your demand and give them a deadline. I've done this once or twice a year most years and it has never failed. Just keep good records of everything and *be sure you are correct* about the battery. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot convert .exe to .deb. It's two completely different things. I don't think running it in Wine will work either. If the so-called support assistant is going to check the battery, it will need to access some things close to the hardware, which would be specific to Windows and your particular computer model.

You could run Windows in a virtual machine, but that wouldn't allow the program to check your battery.

What you really need to do is install Windows on a separate partition or something, which should allow the program to work.

Answer (score 3):

I think only option to run a .exe in a linux machine is by using WINE. You cannot convert a exe to deb.

If you know the complete code of exe program, you can rewrite it for Linux.

I would suggest you to first understand the output of "HP support Assistant" and what data is needed for the support guys at HP to replace your laptop battery.

There are wonderful apps in ubuntu to get all the stats of your computer. which would provide the same results as "HP Support Assistant"

Answer (score 0):

1. use wine from [old post](https://askubuntu.com/q/15518/91632)
2. use hiren's boot cd and run minimal windows live cd then execute your exe file from there
3. install virtualbox and run windows from it then run your exe

Comment: The last option may not be viable as the executable must interface with hardware.

Answer (score 0):

A .EXE file is a Windows Executable Application, which basically means it's a program. A .DEB file, used in Ubuntu and other Debian-based distributions of Linux, is an installer containing the source code of a program, and is not actually the program by itself (the code is, a deb isn't). You can't actually withdraw code from an .EXE once it's become such a format, however, so it would quite technically be impossible to convert such a file to a .deb.

Answer (score 0):

That would involve the makers of the EXE file to either open source their program and have it in a source format like a compressed tar.gz or make them the .deb format. The only way right now is to run it with Wine. In this case, since this is the HP Support Assitant

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert an Exe to a Deb file as an Exe is a compiled program designed to run on Windows and a Deb is an archive that holds files that will be installed on a system that supports Debian's packages management scheme.

The closest solution you will reach given the Wine errors is to run it in a Virtualbox Virtual Machine. This may be enough to "fool" (see next paragraph) the HP techs.

I should also say that having installed Ubuntu you are more than likely violating the terms of the agreement that would provide you with a new battery and even if you do manage to run the software you may already be beyond complying with the exchange agreement.