# How to convert `rm` and `ra` audio files to mp3 in (L)ubuntu?

Tags: sound, mp3, convert

I have radio programs that I have obtained with the extension `rm` and `ra`. How to convert them to mp3 or other more common type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) add medibuntu repository. Instructions [here](http://www.medibuntu.org/repository.php)

2) install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-53

3) Run
`ffmpeg -i inputfile.ra outputfile.mp3`

To use this through a GUI:

- get **[WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/downloads.html)**

Comment: could you improve your answer so as to provide commands for converting multiple files of the same type or of different types? (i mean something like `ffmpeg -i *.ra *.mp3`)

Comment: I think this program only take one file as input, but you can always make a script to run it for multiple files. For example:

`for i in *.ra; do ffmpeg -i $i $(echo $i | sed 's/\.ra/\.mp3/'); done`

Comment: is there a gui for this? it seems much faster than `soundconverter`?

Comment: i don't know soundconverter but ffmpeg is a command line utility. maybe there is some 3rd party frontend

Answer (score 1):

In this case I had to use a piece of heavy artillery I was familiar with in Windows: **[Format Factory](http://www.formatoz.com/)** (for a clean download use [the torrent](http://www.formatoz.com/public/FFSetup300.zip.torrent))

Unzip if needed and install Format Factory ... after [installing Wine](https://askubuntu.com/q/15518/47206), of course.

[image]

A lot of settings are possible

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use sound converter. open up your terminal and type this to install . 
sudo apt-get install soundconverter

Comment: it is an advantage in using a gui for ubuntu: but isn't it a bit slow? it took a lot of more time than the other solutions