# How to install wine on ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: wine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15518/how-do-i-install-wine)
>   [How to install a .tar.gz  (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-to-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

I have downloaded Wine-1.5.18.tar.bz2. I don't know how to install it on ubuntu 12.10. Please help me out of this problem. I don't want to install it from Ubuntu software center.  I have the file that I have already downloaded.

Comment: @user68186 Downloading files from random websites is risky, it has nothing to do with a program being open source or not.

Comment: See this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/224609/should-i-install-programs-from-a-source-tarball-tar-gz-from-the-ubuntu-sof

Answer (score 10):

You have two easy options:

1. You install the one in the official repositories. Open Ubuntu software Center and search for wine and install it. Alternatively in a terminal type `sudo apt-get install wine`.
2. If you wish to have the latest version you're better off adding the official wine ppa.
   In a terminal type: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`
   Followed by `sudo apt-get update` and finally `sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks`