# VLC won't download

Tags: vlc

I'm new to ubuntu and I'm using version 13.10.

I tried to install VLC, but every time I click the download icon it tells me that I need an application to open this link, then invites me to choose one from an empty list.

Comment: we do not usually install by downloading from the Internet. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/224609/should-i-install-programs-from-a-source-tarball-tar-gz-from-the-ubuntu-sof - most software is available from within our distribution's repositories.

Comment: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html

Comment: @Takkat not sure why you are flagging as duplicated.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome, user261173

I Think you were trying installing VLC from VLC website it need to be linked with software center

You can install any package using apt `[sudo apt-get]`

**installing package(s)**

`sudo apt-get install <package-name>`

`<package-name>` can be replaced with following::

google-chrome-stable, pidgin, cheese, audacity, gstreamer, vlc, clementine, guake, gksu, espeak, gedit-plugins, dosbox, playonlinux

i.e - `sudo apt-get install vlc`

```
   sduo apt-get install cheese
```

or You can install more than one packages[softwares] using one statement.

```
   sudo apt-get install vlc cheese pidgin
```

SEE > [Things to do after installing Ubuntu](https://panchal-sagar.blogspot.in/)

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu, you cannot open a `.exe` file. Those are for Windows only.

You have multiple choices for installing a program though :

- Open Ubuntu Software Center, search for "VLC" and click install.
- Open a Terminal, and type `sudo apt-get install vlc`
- Download a `.deb` installation file and open it with the Software Center.

---

To be able to download and install a program found on Ubuntu-related websites in one click, you need to have the package `apturl` installed. Once installed, you can open link *apt://something* with `/usr/bin/apturl-gtk`

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc-nox
```

Comment: Just to note that `vlc-nox` is somewhat a terminal based version of vlc. If you need the full VLC GUI, you would need to install the `vlc` package