# GUI mysql tool for multiple databases

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, mysql, database

I have two discrete mysql databases (located in **different servers**).
In windows, I can use odbc and ms access and query from tables residing in different databases.
In ubuntu, is there a way or tool to do this task?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? It does not matter where the databases are located. Please give us some more detail about your environment.

Comment: database 1 is mysql on IIS server. database 2 is mysql on linux server. I would like to bring (linked) table1 from db1 and table2 from db2 in common db tool and make union query from these 2 tables.

Comment: That link might help you: [mysql-joins-between-databases-on-different-servers-using-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5832787/mysql-joins-between-databases-on-different-servers-using-python)

Comment: Thank you. In addition, the 2 servers are located in different countries. I do not know how to do it using python (I have never used python). I wonder if there is a tool similar with mysqlworkbench I use, I mean GUI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MySql Workbench did not connect to multiple databases at once, I found Tora, a database Management Tool from Oracle. (http://sourceforge.net/projects/tora). You can get build instructions and a precompiled deb for 12.04 here: http://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToBuildToraWithOracle .

It is also available in the official ubuntu-repositories (Software-Center).

Comment: thank you mondjunge. unfortunately, mysql workbench can not connect at the same time in 2 different dbs.

Comment: That is odd... I also found Tora, a database Management Tool from Oracle. (http://sourceforge.net/projects/tora/). You can get it precompiled for 12.04 here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToBuildToraWithOracle . Unfortunately I have no time to test Tora, but it seems like the only tool, that might have such a functionality build in.

Comment: many thanks. I will try it; it seems it is for ubuntu 7.04.

Comment: There is tora 2.1.3. available in ubuntu software center; I have installed in and I connect in both dbs at the same time! Congrats, you can include this in your answer so I accept it.

Comment: I did... thx and good to know that TOra works...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at LibreOffice Base. Its a GUI database system (similar to MS Office Access) that allows you to connect (I believe) to pretty much any database you have login privileges on.

Look in the Ubuntu Software Center and search for LibreOffice Base or run `sudo apt-get install libreoffice-base*` That command will install everything Base needs to run.

Comment: thank you. I have tried, it does import external data (db connect), only one at a time however.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQLyog on Wine/LINUX with GNOME desktop see [product page](https://www.webyog.com/webyog/sqlyogScreenShots?ref=2) in TAB SQLyog on Wine/Linux

[To install  wine.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15518/how-do-i-install-wine)