# how to install programs on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation

hi I'm a youtuber and I need to install my ArcSoft Showbiz capture software but when I put the disc in it comes up with raw files and wont run the set-up menu, also when I try to download things from the internet it wont let me open them it comes up with raw files and wont start the program.

Comment: Video processing in wine with Windows software is probably a bad idea.  Look at the other questions on site that refer to native video editing software for better results.  It's not an answer, but a recommendation, so it's a comment not an answer.

Comment: I used wine. thanks for the help. I would not be able to youtube without your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to run a windows application in Ubuntu for that you have to first install wine and then try running the setup file directly from your media.

Comment: This is valid.  A quick google search turned up it's Windows only software.  I still don't think video production in Wine is a good idea.

Comment: where do i install wine from ??

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15518/how-do-i-install-wine

Comment: you can install wine right from software center.

Comment: I used wine. thanks for the help. I would not be able to youtube without your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can install **Wine**, and then install your software true it.
**But** I don't think video editing on Ubuntu via Wine is a good idea...

There are a bunch of [native programs](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/top5-linux-video-editing-system-software/) for Ubuntu that surely will work better that "ArcSoft Showbiz" via **Wine**.

Comment: I used wine. thanks for the help. I would not be able to youtube without your help.

Comment: @macauley If your problem is answered, close the topic by selecting any answer as **accepted** (Below the _UpVote_ / _DownVote_ buttons).

Comment: what would these programs be ??

Comment: its capturing through my vcap

Comment: The [Lighworks](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/download-lightworks-linux-public-beta.html) is the best (IMO), but it is still BETA as for now. I myself am using [OpenShot](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/02/install-openshot-video-editor-142-on.html) pretty frequently.

Comment: cant find lighworks got openshot but i need to be able to record via usb capture card

Comment: To record from your web-cam try [guvcview](http://guvcview.sourceforge.net/).