# how to use the wine file

Tags: wine

i have downloaded wine application wine application from wine HQ website.
i have the file in .tar format i have downloaded it from an windows 7 installed OS computer.
i have saved and extracted the wine file from my ubuntu 12.04.
The file is stored on this path      "D:\Alladin\ubuntu\wine\wine-1.7.11"        (without doulbe quotes) Now that i have extracted. What all code should i type to compile the wine appllication and make the program.

Note: the path mentioned above is the path given from windows 7 pc and the path has 22 items including the files called "Make.vars.in" and "Makefile.in"
Thankyou.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15518/how-do-i-install-wine

Answer (score 1):

you can skip all that hassle as "Wine" is available in Ubuntu software center.

open it and search wine click on install and you are done