# How do I install steam off a thumb drive

Tags: steam, software-installation

I have steam on a thumb drive and tried to find the installer but the location is unknown. I copied the files from Windows and I can see the files but not the installer.

Answer (score 4):

The Windows version of Steam *will not natively run on Linux*. If you've copied your Steam folder to a USB stick in Windows, this will be the Windows version of Steam. This leads us to several possibilities depending on what it is you're actually trying to do:

## Installing Steam on Linux *without* Internet connection

You will need to download the following file to a memory stick or burn it to some form of optical media:

```
http://media.steampowered.com/client/installer/steam.deb
```

This link is available by browsing to the [Steam Store About Page](http://store.steampowered.com/about/) on a PC running Linux (if you browse to it on a Windows machine you'll get a `.exe` file instead, which isn't natively compatible with Linux).

Once you've got this file copied to your Ubuntu machine, you can install it by running the following command:

```
dpkg -i steam.deb
```

**Note**: you will still need an Internet connection on this machine to actually *run* Steam.

## Installing Steam on Linux *with* Internet connection

To install Steam on Ubuntu, you can simply run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

This will install Steam (which will then update itself on first run, and keep itself updated in future).

## Running it with Wine

The third option for running Steam on Linux is to run the Windows version of Steam on Linux via Wine.

To do this, you will need to [install *Wine*](https://askubuntu.com/q/15518/62483) on your machine.
Once *Wine* is installed, you can run many `.exe` files simply by double clicking on them, like you would do in Windows.

If you've already copied your Steam folder from within Windows, once you've got Wine installed you can run Steam simply by running `Steam.exe` from within the folder you copied.

Answer (score 1):

Hold up.  You're trying to install Steam for Windows on Ubuntu?

If you just copied your Steam folder from Windows straight onto a thumb drive, you can run `steam.exe` in *Wine* and it *should* work.  I think the bigger question lies in what exactly you think you're trying to do.