# Eternal question: How install Wine in Xubuntu 14.04.03 x64?

Tags: xubuntu, wine, 64-bit

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
Recommends: winbind but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

I made all councils which found here. but Wine isn't established. fails depends again(

Comment: can you add the steps that generated the problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install wine?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15518/how-do-i-install-wine)

Answer (score 1):

Try to run `sudo apt-get -f install`.

This will fix dependencies and remove broken packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install wine
```