# You have Held Broken packages...when installing Wine

Tags: wine

I was trying to install Wine. It used to work, but I get this message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

  wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.55-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I get rid of broken packages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install wine?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15518/how-do-i-install-wine)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Answer (score -1):

You can run a check using apt, from the man page;

> check

```
       check is a diagnostic tool; it updates the package cache and checks
       for broken dependencies.
```

Simply run;

```
$ sudo apt-get check
```

You can also try to run your apt-get command with the '-f' option (again from the man page);

> -f, --fix-broken

```
       Fix; attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.
       This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages
       to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. If packages are
       specified, these have to completely correct the problem. The option
       is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT
       itself does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a
       system. It is possible that a system's dependency structure can be
       so corrupt as to require manual intervention (which usually means
       using dpkg --remove to eliminate some of the offending packages).
       Use of this option together with -m may produce an error in some
       situations. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Fix-Broken.
```

Your command would simply be;

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install win1.7
```