# Wine help on 15.10

Tags: wine

I have looked into the question suggestions and haven't found an answer yet. So I am going to ask. I am trying to install Wine and have tried both the Software Center and Terminal methods. I keep getting this.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Is there something I have installed wrong or what? Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install wine?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15518/how-do-i-install-wine)

Answer (score 0):

To install wine write

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install wine1.8
```

Comment: @david Wasn't sure of the latest version.Last time I installed it was 1.7