# Install Wine on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, wine

I'm a totally new user of Linux and just installed 32-bit Kubuntu on a Virtualbox VM to start learning it. I want to install Wine and see how some Windows programs that I still depend on would run. The whole repository and apt-get thing is still very new to me so after trying the advise from various sites and posts to install Wine I gave up. It says that Wine was installed but I can't find it anywhere in the list of programs, nor is there a menu to run an .exe with Wine, so obviously it wasn't installed. Being so new to Linux in general I have no idea what the problem might be.

Can you advise me how to install it and/or **what steps to take to diagnose the problem**?

EDIT: I tried using the repository, searching for wine and installing it, but nothing gets installed even though it says it's installed. I tried the solutions in the suggested answer, but that doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15518/how-do-i-install-wine)

Comment: The question might be a duplicate, but the suggested answers don't solve the problem.

Comment: @Rinzwind even though irrelevant - because I've never used any Linux system before (so I'm not going to jump straight to it).

Comment: I only have a few apps not yet available on Linux, why would I install and run a guest Windows in Linux? To what purpose? I want to switch away from Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It says that Wine was installed but I can't find it anywhere in the list of programs, nor is there a menu to run an .exe with Wine, so obviously it wasn't installed.

Type in command line

```
wine --version
```

If it shows an error you are correct but it is likely to show you a version. "wine" is not a program you run by itself so it does not have a icon to start it from. You need to tell wine it needs to start something. So from command like you would use it like this

```
wine "c:\program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

and it would start internet explorer. Some more on this on [Wine HQ](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/running) and on our [Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine)

There is a 2nd part to wine called "play on linux". It is a set of tools to automate setting up software for using it with wine. So also install [play on linux](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PlayOnLinux). From the link:

> **Why use PlayOnLinux?**

- GUI; no need for the command line interface (CLI).
- Hides the complexity of Wine.
- Uses "virtual drives" (see notes below).
- Some applications are "supported" (e.g. Internet Explorer, Windows Media Player, Microsoft Office, Spore); PlayOnLinux automates their installation.
- You can manually install "unsupported" applications.

The automated install is done by using scripts users made and are proven to work with specific versions numbers of wine.

---

Installation for play on linux:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install playonlinux
sudo apt-get remove playonlinux
```

Play on linux does have an icon you can start and will show you a whole lot of software (though most are probably games (hence the name ;) ))

Comment: Thank you! That's the answer I needed! Indeed I had installed wine - I just didn't understand how it works.