# share it on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wine, shareit

I want to transfer files from my smartphone to the desktop so I can install wine and configure it with windows 7 and download share-it. It got installed alright using Wine but every time I double-click on the share-it shortcut it does not work. I am trying to find out a way to use share-it on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: WINE is pretty much useless. Very few apps **actually** work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try **AirDroid**. It is similar to SHAREit but they also have a native linux variant for transferring from Android to desktop.

There also seems to be **Shareit for Linux**, however I'm not sure how safe this is. Try at your own risk - http://shareitappforpc.com/shareit-for-linux-download.

These are alternatives and probably don't fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Shareit can be installed on Ubuntu 16.04 using wine. Wine installation described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15518/how-do-i-install-wine).

Comment: i already installed wine, configure it and also install share-it but it does not work.