# Can I manage to install on a Dell 15R with all my laptop's features?

Tags: intel-graphics, dell, compatibility

I have a Dell N5010 15R with a 64-bit i3 processor, Intel HD graphics, 320GB hard drive and integrated network card. I wanted to know which Ubuntu version to install in order to have the capacity to use the HD integrated graphics card's full potential.

I want to get in Ubuntu and stop using Windows 7, but will it run programs like FL Studio or Vegas Studio Pro or similar?

Comment: also, i forgo to ask, do i have to install the 32 bit version of ubuntu or the 64 bit? im curious because the 64 bit v of ubuntu says is only for amd processors...

Answer (score 1):

The hardware should work nicely with Ubuntu. You're mentioning Windows applications, and those will not normally run in Ubuntu at all. However, there is something called Wine, which can be used to use Windows applications on Ubuntu. Not everything will work, and not everything will run nicely. You can have a look at http://appdb.winehq.org and search for the applications you need.

Comment: but are there similar programs that can be used in ubuntu, or made for ubuntu?

Comment: Yes there are alternatives, though some people might argue that they can't be compared to their windows counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

Any [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/project/derivatives) [flavor](http://ubuntusite.com/ubuntu-flavors/) will work with your Laptop, They are all the same it's just the GUI and default software (read: [Desktop Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment)) that's different.

About running FL Studio with [WINE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-in-ubuntu): according to WineHQ [it runs almost flawlessly](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=178). [Vegas Studio however won't run at all (except version 9.0e)](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=8957)

Answer (score 1):

You should download and try a live-cd and test it before you touch the hardrive. Just keep in mind than the performance will be even better if you decide to install it on the hardrive. Ubuntu would run like a charm on your configuration (my main computer broke some days ago and right now I'm running it in an old pentium 4 with only 300 mb ram and everything works, so imagine in your i3...)

Also, you could make a dual boot system if you want to keep win7 just in case you change your mind later (but I don't think you do). There's hundreds of tutorials about it.

Comment: I downloaded the image yesterday, and im ready to test it out, hopefully it all works out well... :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a 17R, bought a month or so ago, so the hardware's probably pretty similar.  The only thing with which I've had a problem is the touchpad -- the protocol used by the touchpad isn't entirely reverse-engineered yet.  This means the touchpad will still work, even with side-scrolling, but some of touchpad-specific features (like turning it off when you are typing) are still under (quite active) development.

Comment: thanks for the info, but did ur 17R has an hdmi output? and do you manage to make it work with ubuntu like conecting ur computer to an outside monitor using that output?

Comment: It has HDMI but I haven't actually used it, so I can't help you there.