# How to invoke a X Session and a VM instead of login prompt

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, sdl

The system is Ubuntu 12.04 but the OEM requirement is to make it appear as if it is a Windows system to the end user.   Other VMs and daemons will be active in the system but it is controlled from software that runs in Windows.

What I have done so far is install Windows in a VM (using KVM) using SDL (Simple DirectMedia Layer) as the guest VM's graphics device.  When run in an X Session the Windows graphics environment is displayed in an X window without any problem.   When using the fullscreen option, the Windows environment takes over the entire screen as desired.

So what I need to know are what steps to take such that instead of a getty login prompt at boot time, the Windows environment appears.   This means the X session will have to start (I am using OpenBox as the Window Manager currently but that is not a requirement) and the Windows VM needs to be attached to it.

One sub-question -- I can autostart the Windows VM, but this happens during the upstart process and this is before the X environment runs.   What happens here and can the guest VM's SDL environment be attached to a X server that starts later?

Can anyone guide me on what steps to take?

Comment: This Q&A may give you some ideas on how to do that: http://askubuntu.com/questions/547941/how-to-start-a-vm-on-boot-and-shutdown-on-vm-stop