# How to run a program in a Windows VM and have it be it's own window

Tags: windows, virtualbox, virtualization

I love Ubuntu greatly, but there is one Windows program that I really need to run in Ubuntu: Windows Live Movie Maker (I know, I should be ashamed!).
I have Windows 10 running in Virtual Box. Is there any way to make Windows Live Movie Maker be in it's own window in Ubuntu, and be docked as if it is running on Ubuntu itself?
Also, how do I share files between Ubuntu and the virtualised Windows 10?

Comment: Have you installed the Virtualbox Guest Additions in the VM? Enable [seamless mode](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#seamlesswindows).

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/153894/launch-an-application-in-windows-from-the-ubuntu-desktop for how to have this with an own  Launcher.

Comment: Muru is right, you need seamless mode (Host + C)

Comment: @muru VirtualBox claims "Seamless Mode" is Host + L, but when I try Host + L, VirtualBox crashes. When I try Host + C, it switches from windowed mode to full screen and vice versa.

Comment: @HillierProductions Which version of VirtualBox?

Comment: @muru VirtualBox 5.0.10