# Run command in virtual box using VBoxManage?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

I am building out a python script that automatically starts the virtual box run a file in virtual box and take snapshot of the VM. So i am planning to use VBoxManage which is command line tool in ubuntu.

To start VM i am using

```
VBoxManage controlvm        uuid|name
                            pause|resume|reset|poweroff|savestate|
                            acpipowerbutton|acpisleepbutton|
```

But to run command i did not find any command.
Can anyone suggest me any other way to execute a command in virtual box using command line in ubuntu?

Comment: If you want to run a command within the guest environment, vboxmanage cannot do that. The command will have to be scripted within the guest. It may be helpful to describe what you want to do in more detail.

Comment: You may be able to execute a guest application using `VBoxmanage` `guestcontrol` but I haven't yet figured out how to pass any parameters to this application. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/153894/launch-an-application-in-windows-from-the-ubuntu-desktop and https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-guestcontrol

Comment: I read about it, but i guess  Launching in guestcontrol will not give full privilege i.e will not give permission to run as root.