# connecting to a single remote windows application 16.04

Tags: windows, virtualbox, remote-desktop, remote

It seems it was possible to do this at one point with `winconn`, but it is not available for 16.04, and it seems `remmina` doesn't work with the `remote app tool` for Windows. Does anybody know about a solution? I keep around a virtualbox windows 10, but it is not very comfortable to use apps inside the window of the virtualbox (if I capture special keys it makes changing apps difficult, if I don't capture keys it makes working within the app harder ...), so I am looking for a solution to run my windows apps inside virtualbox, but accessing them as a normal window from ubuntu.

Comment: For a virtualized Windows it would be VirtualBox "seamless mode" but with W10 it does not work well on my system (presumably because of GPU driver issues): https://askubuntu.com/questions/153894/launch-an-application-in-windows-from-the-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Not bad :) Although I did have it freeze on me. It also doesn't solve the issues with keyboard capture. My biggest problem is, that if I enable keyboard capture in VB, then alt-tab will, alt-tab in windows and not in ubuntu (also workspace switching will not work), on the other hand, if I disable it, I can't type any characters that require alt to type (I have a few on my Hungarian keyboard layout).

Comment: VB should - **should** - only capture the keys of a window in focus. So as long as we do not select the VB instance to have focus it should work (sorry that I can't test  because of said graphics issues).