# How can I use the VMware Unity feature from an Ubuntu host?

Tags: unity, virtualization

I used the Unity feature of VMware Player, which allows you to display windows from the guest directly on the host system.

But according to the [VMWare community forums](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/518568) , the Unity feature has been removed for Linux hosts in Player Version 12.

What else can I use to provide this feature?

Comment: What is the unity feature? Do you mean `wine`?

Comment: @derHugo it is a helpful feature to use any software in the guest outside the VM, like Wine but for me it's better. https://communities.vmware.com/thread/518568

Comment: @chaske other VM softwares also support this feature but in other names

Comment: @chaskes and is this feature work in VBox?

Comment: You need to install the guest additions into your guest and then seamless mode in vbox will be available. Supposed to be essentially the same as unity mode for vmware.

Comment: In VirtualBox it is called "seamless" mode. See e.g. https://askubuntu.com/a/154232/3940

Comment: @Meky Your link didn't really help me ... but what Takkat mentioned seems to be what you are looking for. I only know this feature for VirtualBox .. didn't see this in Vmware so far.

Comment: Thanks @chaske you really helped me, VB really good and the Seamless was perfect and it's exactly what I need.

Comment: Glad it worked out. I'm going to edit your question and make an answer, since no one else has jumped in yet. There are other questions on seamless mode, but none of them appear to be a dupe of this one that I saw.

Comment: Thanks also @Takkat you also helped me and now the Seamless working 100% with me :)

Comment: Yes @derHugo exactly, Seamless was what I need, thanks

Comment: Yes @chaskes I think a lot of users will need your answer specially who moved from Mac to Ubuntu, The Seamless or Unity was very important for me on Mac and I missed it when I moved to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Seamless Mode (also called [seamless windows](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#seamlesswindows) ) in VirtualBox.

> With the "seamless windows" feature of VirtualBox, you can have the windows that are displayed within a virtual machine appear side by side next to the windows of your host.
>
> To enable seamless mode, after starting the virtual machine, press the Host key (normally the right control key) together with "L". This will enlarge the size of the VM's display to the size of your host screen and mask out the guest operating system's background.
>
> To go back to the "normal" VM display (i.e. to disable seamless windows), press the Host key and "L" again.

(Source: VirtualBox [seamless windows](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#seamlesswindows) in online help)

In order to use seamless windows, you need to first install the VirtualBox guest additions.