# Why Can't I Download Certain Software?

Tags: downloads, executable

I just installed Ubuntu. Totally new to it. I tried to download to different things from the Internet (RealPlayer and YouTube Downloader), but when I try to open the file(s) to install an archive box pops up saying that I can't. What's the problem here? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

The message I get is:

```
Archive:  /home/justanotherpoet/Downloads/RealPlayer.exe
Zip file size: 760128 bytes, number of entries: 35584

   [/home/justanotherpoet/Downloads/RealPlayer.exe]:
     Zipfile is disk 46863 of a multi-disk archive, and this is not the disk on
     which the central zipfile directory begins (disk 42501).
```

Comment: You cannot use Windows software on Linux, except using a Windows-emulator like Wine, although it's preferred if you use native Linux programs. Please use the Ubuntu Software Center to download the required software. Click on the button on the top-left corner and type Ubuntu Software Center and then click on the icon saying that. There browse/search for the software you need and you can install them like that.

Comment: @nitstorm Just for future reference, WINE is not an emulator, it is a compatibility layer.

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS Sorry, my bad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Windows software or games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Answer (score 2):

You are downloading Windows software and attempting to install it on Linux. Windows installation packages will not work (without installing the Windows compatibility layer, Wine) ; but it's usually best to find a native Linux program for a given task.

Installing software in Ubuntu is usually done through the software centre, or the Synaptic package manager, or using the command line `apt-get` utility. You can download .deb packages, or even download sources and compile them, but it's usually best to use a package manager if you can.

- For media playback, try the default Movie Player (Totem) or VLC
- If you want to download YouTube content, check out [this thread](http://www.howtogeek.com/?post_type=post&p=1399), especially the complete comments section.

Comment: I dont know, that all seems a bit too complicated for me. Isn't there a simpler solution, such as some Linux-compatible software that will handle everything for me (including converting to Mp3)?

Comment: @user76436 Look in Ubuntu Software Center, and install Wine and try opening the RealPlayer installer again, or use a piece of software supported in Ubuntu Linux(If you can find a download that's a DEB file, you should be able to install it)