# support for .exe?

Tags: 12.04, windows

I am somewhat annoyed by the fact that most programs/games/everything else seems to be Windows only (.exe). Is there something that allows Ubuntu to support/run .exe files? Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend you check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software

Comment: Ubuntu is not a drop in replacement for Windows. In addition, there is an extreemely large set of porgrams available in the repositories. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware If all you want to do is run .exe I suggest you stay with windows. If you want to run Ubuntu, look at Linux native alternates for your .exe , see http://www.linuxalt.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a very good project called WINE. You could try that by typing

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

It will automatically associate *.exe* files to be opened by WINE.

See: http://appdb.winehq.org/ for supported apps and games.

Comment: No problem. It will be good if you could check your question as solved.

Comment: I'll do that as soon as the site lets me...