# Why does Ubuntu fail to run .exe files? / How do I run .exe?

Tags: windows, wine, executable

So, I just built my PC today, and am only using Ubuntu until I get Windows installed (sorry, guys!) But when I go to click on any .exe file, nothing happens.  It just sits there.  No error message, nothing.  I've seen other people with similar problems, but they all get an error message.  But not me... Whats going on?  How do I fix this?  Help?

Comment: Also see: [How can I install Windows software? also games?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-also-games)