# How to run Windows executable Files

Tags: 12.04

Having shifted from Windows a while ago, there are still some applications that I wish were also designed to run on Linux platform. Therefore, how can the executable files of such applications be enabled to run on Pangolin Precise if there is any chance?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Your question seems to be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/988/58950. If those answers don't fully   
address your question, please edit it to include why. Thanks!

Comment: It will be really useful if you tell us which kind of executables, made by yourself? a programmer? a commercial application? This improvement to your question will be helpful to receive the proper support. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be looking for is Wine. The problem with Wine is that not every program will work.

You can get more info about Wine [here](http://www.winehq.org/)

To install it go [here](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu)

Or if you don't mind working in the terminal you can use the following easy commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.5
```