# Will "World Of Tanks" run on Ubuntu?

Tags: windows, wine, games

I play world of tanks (a Game) in windows. Will it work on ubuntu? Better, worse, same? I would like to try Ubuntu but not if w.o.t won't work.

Comment: It's rated Gold in [Wine's AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11544).

Comment: Making an OS choice based on a game is rather silly. Instead pick the best tool for the job. If you really want a huge WOT power house then consider they only support windows, and use it (and I *hate* saying that). If you have other reasons to use Linux then consider that they are likely more important the WOT. Linux is the best tool for a lot of jobs, but WOT is not among them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games

Comment: This is not duplicate as there are "port" to install WoT with tweaks, compatible wine included. below my answer how to use it.

Answer (score 6):

World of Tanks is available for Windows only as I see on the Website.
But there are possibilities to run Windows software on Linux.

### Wine

Wine is a program that allows you to install and use Windows programs. It's not perfect, but there is a database where you can see whether the program worked according to other people. This link was already posted in the comments of your question: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11544

As you can see the newest versions of the game are rated in "GOLD", the game should run fine. Details can also be found in this database.

Since Wine is a bit complicated to new or inexperienced users, I recommend using Wine via 
**Crossover** (http://www.codeweavers.com/products/) 
or **PlayOnLinux**(Free, downloadable in Software Center).

These programs will use Wine to run windows software, but offer an easier interface. You can also try using Wine without this software. Just look for "Wine" in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Please keep in mind, that even with this database, and even if I would try it out for you, there is no guarantee that it will work on your specific hardware. It's not a native solution, but a workaround. It's GOLD rating looks promising, through.

Comment: here a post of WOT community to run it: https://worldoftanks.eu/en/content/soft/pc_programs/1311/

Answer (score 2):

Just works under **wine** `3.21-staging` and up.
Current stable version is 4.0.

Based on wine's [application database](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11544), the game has gold status, which means it should work without any problems. If something goes wrong, check the [linked website](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=36493) for all the available workarounds.

---

### Install

If your system is `x64`, you need to enable `x86` architecture

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Download and add the repository key

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
```

Add the repository based on your ubuntu version

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ cosmic main'
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ xenial main'
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ trusty main'
```

Update packages with

```
sudo apt update
```

Install one of the following packages

Note, that there is **no space** between winehq-stable etc.

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-devel
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work under Wine (compatibility layer for Windows' apps under Ubuntu). Just install Wine under Ubuntu and install your game with Wine. Look [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11544) for more info.

For more info about installing Wine see [this Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/989/21195).

Answer (score 1):

i think that you should try out a program called lutris. Its completely free, automatically sets the correct wine versions for your games and has a fast-growing community. You can download the program here : https://lutris.net/downloads/ . After installing lutris, just click here : https://lutris.net/games/world-of-tanks/ ,and install WoT.

Answer (score 0):

**PortWoT** - http://portwine-linux.ru/world-of-tanks-linux/

WoT have gold status in wine db, but I had unable to install it, launcher crashes. Port WoT is a solution. It keep updated for years and work fine.

> PortWoT - is the port for the client World Of Tanks 1.x (SD and HD
>   customers)  under Linux through WINE . With a convenient and simple
>   graphical installer, maximum performance and native WoTtweaker `th.

This is a some kind of port, but uses original client with patches to it and patches to wine. Find on page download link (on Russian 'Скачать') There are GB flag on left-down on page for English version.

Download shell script, and run it:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sh ./PortWoT-134
```

Launcher need xterm, I don't know why, but just install it 'sudo apt-get install xterm'

Then run WoT launcher from applications menu. Install of WoT started.

> So, if there is already a client downloaded the WoT , you can throw in
>   a ~ / PortWoT / drive_c / Games is / World_of_Tanks / (here kept most
>   common client the WoT )

I haven't try to install non Russian client, may be above quote is the way to install on different language.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, World of Tanks runs on Linux. Here is a way to install it under Xubuntu 20.04 LTS:**

If you feel you don’t want to «defile» your Ubuntu installation with Windows you can **install World of Tanks in an external disk drive** and for that follow this section, otherwise, skip to the **WINE Installation** section.

#### Installing Xubuntu on an external disk

Requirements:

- An external disk drive with a minimum of 250 GB with no data.
- A pen drive with a live image of Xubuntu 20.04 LTS.

1. Connect your external disk drive.
2. Open the app **Disks** (gnome-disks) and delete all partitions of your external disk drive. **Please be VERY careful with this and check that the external disk drive is selected.**
3. Reboot your computer and access the boot menu. Select the pen drive with the live image of  Xubuntu 20.04 LTS.
4. Follow the installation procedure until the installation options menu.
5. Choose Escolher **One more thing**
6. Now be *VERY careful* with the following:

   For each partition, when clicking on **Modify**, confirm that the existing partitions have **Do not use partition** selected, including the swap partition. **Do not check the pen drive with live image of Xubuntu**
7. Identify the external disk partition and delete it in order to get the **free space** information for the entire external disk drive.
8. Select the external disk drive and create an 8GB partition as **Swap** with the following properties: **Logical** and **End of space**.
9. Create a partition with the remain disk space as `/` (root) with the following properties: **Primary**, **EXT4**, **Beginning space**

   **VERY IMPORTANT**: at the bottom of the window select the external disk drive as **Boot loader installation device**.
10. Click on **Install now** and then **Continue**.
11. In the next step choose the machine name and administrator account with a strong password.
12. Open a Terminal window and run the following commands:

    ```
    sudo apt update
    sudo apt upgrade
    ```

    select `Yes`

    ```
    sudo apt auto remove
    sudo apt autoclean
    sudo apt install gufw
    ```

    (graphical interface for the firewall)
    sudo gufw enable
    (activate the firewall)
    Close the `Terminal` window
13. Reboot and enter the boot menu, and select the external disk drive with the Xubuntu 20.04 LTS.
14. It strongly suggest the creation of a user account with user permissions in order to run the game. For security reasons is not recommended to use the administrator account to run wine programs, the game nor for daily usage!** So, select **Configurations manager > Users and Groups**   select **Add** and enter the administrator password, create a user name, select **OK**, select the account type as **User**, create a strong password, save the settings.

#### WINE installation:

This wine installation procedure was tested for gaming purposes and is working on Xubuntu 20.04.x LTS machines.

See https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu for additional information

Open the app Terminal and execute the following commands:

```
su – administratoraccount
```

and enter the password.

Add 32-bit architecture to make 32-bit packages available

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Download repository key:

```
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
sudo apt-key add winehq.key
```

Add the repository for Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'
```

Update packages:

```
sudo apt update
```

Install the **Development branch** wine package:

```
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

Install winetricks:

```
sudo apt install winetricks
```

Install dxvk package:

```
sudo apt install dxvk
```

Checking wine version installed: `wine --version`

#### LUTRIS installation:

See https://lutris.net/downloads/

1. Execute the following commands with administrator rights:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lutris-team/lutris
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install lutris
   sudo apt update
   ```
2. Reboot

#### WORLD OF TANKS installation via Lutris:

1. Go to: https://lutris.net/games/world-of-tanks/
2. Select **Wine EU DXVK / win7 version**
3. Click on **Install**, select **Lutris** and click on **Open connection**
4. Click on **Install** (click on **View source** if you want to check the installation script)
5. Click on **Install**
6. Accept the installation of Mono and Gekko

   At this stage if an error is displayed please start again from 1.
7. Select the desktop shortcuts and click on **Launch** and the game will be listen in the Lutris library
8. On **Lutris** click **Configure** (settings gear)
9. Open the tab  **Game options > Virtual Desktop Resolution** and set the resolution to match you screen resolution, then click **Save**
10. Select the tab **Game options > Executable**, then click on **Browse** and point the way to: `home/uwot/Games/world-of-tanks/drive_c/ProgramData/Wargaming.net/GameCenter/wgc.exe` and **Save**
11. If the game is in the Russian language, click on **Configure** (settings gear) and select **English** then **Save** > click on **World of tanks** and select **SD or HD > Accept & Install > Yes**

    *Please note that if we pause the installation and resume, we must quickly click on the Game Center icon.* Another option is pointing the way to: `/home/uwot/Games/world-of-tanks/drive_c/Program Files/ Wargaming.net/GameCenter/setup.exe`
12. Click on **Save**
13. After starting to update and to enter correctly, click on **Settings** and open the **Game options** tab then **Executable**, click on **Browse** and point the way to: `/home/uwot/Games/world-of-tanks/drive_c/Games/World_of_Tanks_EU/wgc_api.exe`
14. When the updates are finished open the **Game options → Executable → Browse** and point the way to: `/home/uwot/Games/world-of-tanks/drive_c/Games/World_of_Tanks_EU/WorldOfTanks.exe`

#### World of Tanks updates

Normally, when entering the game if the notification «Connection interrupted» appears, this means that an update is available. However if we select **OK**, and then update the application it will not update and an error code is displayed. How to proceed:

1. Click on **Start later**
2. Open **Lutris** and **Stop** World of Tanks
3. Right click on **World of Tanks > Configure > Game options > Executable > Browse** to `/home/username/Games/world-of-tanks/drive_c/Program Files/ Wargaming.net/GameCenter/wgc.exe` and click **OK**.
4. Open the tab **Runner options > Wine version >** select **WineHQ Devel (X.X-rcX) > Save**
5. On **Lutris > World of Tanks** click **Play** and the Wargaming Center should start the download
6. After the installation it is necessary to set back the changes. So, back to **Lutris** and **Stop** the game
7. Right click on **World of Tanks > Configure > Game options > Executable > Browse** to `/home/username/Games/world-of-tanks/drive_c/Games/World_of_Tanks_EU/WorldOfTanks.exe` and click **OK**
8. Open the tab **Runner options > Wine version >** select **lutris-X.X-X-x86_64 (default) > Browse** to `/home/username/Games/world-of-tanks/drive_c/Games/World_of_Tanks_EU/WorldOfTanks.exe` and click **OK > Save**
9. Click **Play** to start the game
10. **Troubleshooting**

- **Error updating the Wargaming.net Game Center (9019)**:
  Open **Game Center** as described on point 10 of WORLD OF TANKS installation via Lutris > select **Game configuration > reinstall Game Center**
- **Unable to update the game (3000)**:
  a) Follow the procedure above (starting at point 1) and if doesn't work, on Lutris, select **Kill all wine processes**
  b) In `/home/username/Games/world-of-tanks/drive_c/Games/World_of_Tanks_EU/` rename the folder **Updates** to **Updates_old**
  c) Restart the game
  d) If doesn't work, on Lutris, select **Kill all wine processes** > **delete** the folder **Updates** and rename back the folder **Updates_old** to **Updates**
  e) Start the game and should work now.

#### In-game troubleshooting

- If the function keys (4, 5 or 6) don't work use
  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>mouse</kbd> and minimize the game window, maximize, minimize again and maximize again. Knowing this, after that, you can do it during the lauching game countdown.