# What is causing terrible performance for World of Tanks in Wine/PlayOnLinux?

Tags: 14.04, wine, games, playonlinux

I recently installed World of Tanks using PlayOnLinux in Ubuntu 14.04. I've gotten past any obstacles to installation, and the launcher runs smoothly enough, but when the actual game client opens, poor fps renders it entirely unplayable. My cursor only moves every five seconds or so, and that's only in the menu. The game reports 5 fps, but it must be lower. I'm using Wine version 1.7.54 and the Windows 7 option for this. What can improve my performance?

Answer (score 1):

A WineHQ page says that World of Tanks works rather well on 12.10 after adding these: `d3dx9_36` `gecko` `corefonts` `d3dx9_43` `msxml3` `wininet` `ie7` `w_workaround_wine_bug-21947` `msxml6`

I can't remember exactly how to add these (and I'm not currently in Ubuntu), but it should be easy to find. If you can't get it, I'll reboot into Ubuntu and help you out.

Source: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=27800&iTestingId=79097

Comment: I installed all of those things, and now the game won't even start.

Comment: Ooh, yikes. How did you install them? Give me a process.

Comment: Configure->Install Components on PlayOnLinux got me to a list of additional programs, those you mentioned among them, with the notable exception of the workaround one.

Comment: Hmm, OK. I think, since it's for 12.10, it might just not work out. You can check the other Ubuntu tests on WineHQ and see if they suggest anything different.

Answer (score 0):

PortWoT have tweaks to improve perfomance, and also native wottweaker coming with port can affect perfomance.

PortWoT - http://portwine-linux.ru/world-of-tanks-linux/

WoT have gold status in wine db, but I had unable to install it, launcher crashes. Port WoT is a solution. It keep updated for years and work fine.

> PortWoT - is the port for the client World Of Tanks 1.x (SD and HD
>   customers) under Linux through WINE . With a convenient and simple
>   graphical installer, maximum performance and native WoTtweaker `th.

Here are full explanation in my answer:  [Will "World Of Tanks" run on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295866/will-world-of-tanks-run-on-ubuntu)